# How do I rename all folders and files to lowercase on Linux?

Tags: linux, rename, lowercase

I have to rename a complete folder tree recursively so that no uppercase letter appears anywhere (it's C++ source code, but that shouldn't matter).

Bonus points for ignoring CVS and Subversion version control files/folders. The preferred way would be a shell script, since a shell should be available on any Linux box.

There were some valid arguments about details of the file renaming.

1. I think files with the same lowercase names should be overwritten; it's the user's problem. When checked out on a case-ignoring file system, it would overwrite the first one with the latter, too.
2. I would consider A-Z characters and transform them to a-z, everything else is just calling for problems (at least with source code).
3. The script would be needed to run a build on a Linux system, so I think changes to CVS or Subversion version control files should be omitted. After all, it's just a scratch checkout. Maybe an "export" is more appropriate.

Comment: The previously posted will work perfectly out of the box or with a few adjustments for simple cases, but there are some situations you might want to take into account before running the batch rename: 1. What should happen if you have two or more names at the same level in the path hierarchy which differ only by case, such as `ABCdef`, `abcDEF` and `aBcDeF`? Should the rename script abort or just warn and continue? 2. How do you define lower case for non US-ASCII names? If such names might be present, should one check and exclude pass be performed first? 3. If you are running a rename operation

Answer (score 202, accepted):

A concise version using the `"rename"` command:

```
find my_root_dir -depth -exec rename 's/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\L$2/' {} \;
```

This avoids problems with directories being renamed before files and trying to move files into non-existing directories (e.g. `"A/A"` into `"a/a"`).

Or, a more verbose version without using `"rename"`.

```
for SRC in `find my_root_dir -depth`
do
    DST=`dirname "${SRC}"`/`basename "${SRC}" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
    if [ "${SRC}" != "${DST}" ]
    then
        [ ! -e "${DST}" ] && mv -T "${SRC}" "${DST}" || echo "${SRC} was not renamed"
    fi
done
```

#### P.S.

The latter allows more flexibility with the move command (for example, `"svn mv"`).

Comment: using rename can be done this way as well
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *

Comment: Beware, both versions won't work on a case insensitive filesystem. In my case I replaced the `then`-enclosed line by `(mv "${SRC}" "${DST}.renametmp" && mv "${DST}.renametmp" "${DST}") || echo "${SRC} was not renamed"`.

Comment: The second approach didn't work correctly for me with files containing blank spaces (context: linux, bash).

Comment: Using the last version of rename, no regex is needed. The full command becomes `find my_root_dir -depth -exec rename -c {} \;`. Add -f to rename if you're on a case-insensitive filesystem (eg Mac)

Comment: The second one worked for me on Solaris by removing the `-T` from the `mv` command.

Comment: Using `find ... | while read -r SRC` in place of the `for` loop fixed problems with whitespace for me. (Mac OS)

Comment: +1 for the second option. The first one didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: If you're using this in a git repo, make sure not to rename anything in your `.git` folder.

Comment: the first one worked for me on ubuntu 12.04 LTS, thanks for both options!

Comment: I had to add a `-f` to get the rename to work. I kept getting a warning saying the file already existed.

Comment: make sure you actually have `rename`... for OSX, `brew install rename`

Comment: find my_root_dir -depth -exec rename 's/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\L$2/' {} \;

This code works but I want it in reverse lowercase to uppercase how do I do it?

Comment: whats the change make in first script if we want to rename only folders and sub folders,not files?

Comment: @tzury Bar Yochay's regexp does not work when the directory is multiple levels deep.

Comment: using which version of `rename`?

Answer (score 338):

Smaller still I quite like:

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

On case insensitive filesystems such as OS X's [HFS+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus), you will want to add the `-f` flag:

```
rename -f 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

Comment: http://linux.icydog.net/rename.php: `The renaming utility that comes by default with Ubuntu is a Perl program sometimes called prename`

Comment: Thanks, I used it in this way $ find | xargs rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *

Comment: Hmm... I get "'./ABC.txt' not renamed. './abc.txt' already exists" even though it doesn't.

Comment: If in that folder there's too much stuff (rename isn't able to handle more than a given number of elements (I have got about 99k files) giving you the message "Argument list too long"), you can go with `find . -exec rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' {} \;`

Comment: This assumes you have perls rename, which is not the case always. e.g. on my debian rename is completely different

Comment: On Arch, the program is called `perl-rename` (and is provided by a package with the same name)

Comment: @user456584 you're using a case-insensitive filesystem, so `abc.txt` and `ABC.txt` there are a same file (a.k.a NTFS or VFAT). Use the `-f` flag

Comment: This doesn't answer the given problem since "rename" is not recursive.

Comment: y is transliterate? I couldn't find anything about 'y' in the man page of rename  (on Ubuntu 16.10 or OSX with bash version 3.2.57) but found this under sed? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/sed.1.html

Comment: on OSX make sure you have rename. `brew install rename`

Comment: Most importantly: Unlike the other answers, one can actually remember this!

Comment: `rename -c *` or `rename -cf *` is shorter.

Comment: @reallynice the idea is interesting but I had to run it several times as there was many depths of folders, but is working little by little thx :)

Comment: Given `/tmp/AAA/BBB` `/tmp/AAA/CCC`, `rename -f 'y/A-Z/a-z/' /tmp/AAA/*` still return `/tmp/aaa/bbb: No such file or directory` on a case-sensitive filesystem, `-f` flag doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Add `-v` to see what is changed.

Comment: On Fedora the package is `prename`: "prename.noarch : Perl script to rename multiple files"

Comment: you can make rename `recursive` just by changing the address: `rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' ./*/*`

Comment: FYI for future readers. This doesn't work on WSL (windows files from Linux). You get a "file already exists". More a function of how the OS combination works. I ended up doing something like ```find . -depth | rename -v -n -d 'y/A-Z\./a-z+/'``` followed by ```find . -depth | rename -n -v -d "s/\+/\./g"```. Of course for such a hack to work, you need to be sure no file names contain +. Which you can check by doing ```find . -iname "*+*"```

Comment: This doesn't work on case-sensitive file systems on macOS because it says the file already exists.

Answer (score 116):

```
for f in `find .`; do mv -v "$f" "`echo $f | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`"; done
```

Note: The dot is required for macOS compatibility, but it still works on Linux.

Comment: Please do a "mkdir -p A/B/C" before running your script.

Comment: "find" should be replaced by whatever command you use to get a list of the files you wish to rename; for example, "ls *.{C,CPP,H}".

Comment: `for f in *.txt; do mv -v $f `echo $f | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`; done` Works with spaces on debian.

Comment: Doesn't work on OS X, just prints the usage info for `find`. `find .` seems to fix this.

Comment: The "consolidated" version, from all comments (answer can't be edited anymore): ```for f in `find .`; do mv -v "$f" "`echo $f | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`"; done```

Comment: @romaricdrigon - I went with your version (on macOS), and it works perfectly.

Comment: my output is `'[A-Z] [error opening dir]'$'\n''[a-z] [error opening dir]'$'\n\n''0 directories, 0 files'` on `lubuntu` 16.4

Comment: Can someone explain to my why this should work in the first place? If it finds ./FOO and ./FOO/BAR, it first renames ./FOO to ./foo, after which it can no longer find ./FOO/BAR. Entering my own answer below that should fix this.

Comment: how can rename only folders name?

Comment: This isn't working for file paths with spaces in it.

Answer (score 114):

Just simply try the following if you don't need to care about efficiency.

```
zip -r foo.zip foo/*
unzip -LL foo.zip
```

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty inefficient way.

Comment: Assuming that computational efficiency is typically NOT a concern when you find yourself needing to rename files in a directory... I think this is probably the most creatively simple solution on this thread.

Really something this trivial should not be as complicated as the accepted answers demonstrate and this workaround is far more proportionate to the amount of thought I want to invest in an operation like this. +1000

Comment: @peter what's more, it works!  I tried using the other more complex answers, and for whatever reason that was beyond my willingness to debug, they simply were not working.  this simple one works like a charm!

Comment: This is hilarious-- I just tried it and it worked wonders. Definitely simpler than writing a script.

Comment: You can speed it up with `-0` (that's 'zero', no compression) switch, `zip -0 -r foo.zip foo/`.

Comment: #ingenious!! I thought on making a gradual folder name changing (changes top folders prior to inner ones, and re-scan it all) and so on.. but this works great! thx! btw `unrar x -cl "file.rar" "somefolder/"`

Comment: This will not remove any files with the uppercase characters, which actually worked better in my case. But, you can delete the directory in between the two operations to ensure that the result contains only the files with lowercase names.

Comment: I had to change over 50'000 filenames in different directory structures. The original accepted answer did barely 10% the work in 2 minutes where this, with the `-0` compression, was almost instant!

Comment: This is not just inefficient. This one is simply **impossible** if there is not enough free space for a temporary archive.

Comment: I know it's a dumb and inefficient method but it was the fastest way for me on WSL because Windows was being pissy about there already being a file with the upper case name.

Comment: how can rename only folders and sub folders name. not files

Comment: This is a good solution for files that are small enough in size. If you have large files (for example I needed to change names of high resolution pictures and videos), this solution would be painfully slow. Plus of course you need a lot of free space.

Answer (score 26):

One can simply use the following which is less complicated:

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

Comment: This does not work, it says that file with lowercased name already exist.

Comment: @kirhgoff I've seen that happen with NFS mounts -- follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/546429).

Comment: This doesn't add anything to [this identical answer posted 6 years earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8167105/6243352).

Comment: To avoid the "already exist" error, add `-f`:
 `rename -f 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *`

Answer (score 22):

This works on [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)/[Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) or other distributions without the `rename` Perl script:

```
for i in $( ls | grep [A-Z] ); do mv -i "$i" "`echo $i | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'`"; done
```

Source: *[Rename all file names from uppercase to lowercase characters](https://linuxconfig.org/rename-all-files-from-uppercase-to-lowercase-characters)*

(In some distributions the default `rename` command comes from util-linux, and that is a different, incompatible tool.)

Comment: This only works on a single directory, not recursively

Comment: Coool.. Works well

Answer (score 22):

The simplest approach I found on Mac OS X  was to use the rename package from http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/:

```
brew install rename
rename --force --lower-case --nows *
```

> --force Rename even when a file with the destination name already exists.
>
> --lower-case Convert file names to all lower case.
>
> --nows Replace all sequences of whitespace in the filename with single underscore characters.

Answer (score 18):

This works if you already have or set up the **rename** command (e.g. through [brew install](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29) in Mac):

```
rename --lower-case --force somedir/*
```

Comment: ... if you set up rename first, e.g. through `brew install rename`

Comment: rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *

Comment: `--lower-case`? That's not the case in Arch Linux at least, sadly.

Comment: `rename` is not a bash builtin.  It is an external utility and syntax will differ depending on the version you have installed.  This answer is not sufficient as a portable solution "for all unix based OS" as claimed.

Comment: Just checked, the `rename` command included in the latest Fedora (28), through `util-linux-2.31` package, does not have the `--lower-case` option.

Answer (score 16):

Most of the answers above are dangerous, because they do not deal with names containing odd characters. Your safest bet for this kind of thing is to use `find`'s `-print0` option, which will terminate filenames with ASCII NUL instead of \n.

Here is a script, which only alter files and not directory names so as not to confuse `find`:

```
find .  -type f -print0 | xargs -0n 1 bash -c \
's=$(dirname "$0")/$(basename "$0");
d=$(dirname "$0")/$(basename "$0"|tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]"); mv -f "$s" "$d"'
```

I tested it, and it works with filenames containing spaces, all kinds of quotes, etc. This is important because if you run, as root, one of those other scripts on a tree that includes the file created by

```
touch \;\ echo\ hacker::0:0:hacker:\$\'\057\'root:\$\'\057\'bin\$\'\057\'bash
```

... well guess what ...

Comment: It would be more simple to use `rename` instead of `mv`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my suboptimal solution, using a Bash shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# First, rename all folders
for f in `find . -depth ! -name CVS -type d`; do
   g=`dirname "$f"`/`basename "$f" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
   if [ "xxx$f" != "xxx$g" ]; then
      echo "Renaming folder $f"
      mv -f "$f" "$g"
   fi
done

# Now, rename all files
for f in `find . ! -type d`; do
   g=`dirname "$f"`/`basename "$f" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
   if [ "xxx$f" != "xxx$g" ]; then
      echo "Renaming file $f"
      mv -f "$f" "$g"
   fi
done
```

Folders are all renamed correctly, and `mv` isn't asking questions when permissions don't match, and CVS folders are not renamed (CVS control files inside that folder are still renamed, unfortunately).

Since "find -depth" and "find | sort -r" both return the folder list in a usable order for renaming, I preferred using "-depth" for searching folders.

Comment: Your first find does not work. Try "mkdir -p A/B/C" and then running your script.

Answer (score 6):

One-liner:

```
for F in K*; do NEWNAME=$(echo "$F" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'); mv "$F" "$NEWNAME"; done
```

Or even:

```
for F in K*; do mv "$F" "${F,,}"; done
```

Note that this will convert only files/directories starting with letter K, so adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Using Larry Wall's filename fixer:

```
$op = shift or die $help;
chomp(@ARGV = <STDIN>) unless @ARGV;
for (@ARGV) {
    $was = $_;
    eval $op;
    die $@ if $@;
    rename($was,$_) unless $was eq $_;
}
```

It's as simple as

```
find | fix 'tr/A-Z/a-z/'
```

(where `fix` is of course the script above)

Answer (score 5):

The original question asked for ignoring SVN and CVS directories, which can be done by adding -prune to the find command. E.g to ignore CVS:

```
find . -name CVS -prune -o -exec mv '{}' `echo {} | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'` \; -print
```

[edit] I tried this out, and embedding the lower-case translation inside the find didn't work for reasons I don't actually understand. So, amend this to:

```
$> cat > tolower
#!/bin/bash
mv $1 `echo $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
^D
$> chmod u+x tolower 
$> find . -name CVS -prune -o -exec tolower '{}'  \;
```

Ian

Answer (score 5):

Not portable, Zsh only, but pretty concise.

First, make sure `zmv` is loaded.

```
autoload -U zmv
```

Also, make sure `extendedglob` is on:

```
setopt extendedglob
```

Then use:

```
zmv '(**/)(*)~CVS~**/CVS' '${1}${(L)2}'
```

To recursively lowercase files and directories where the name is not *CVS*.

Answer (score 5):

This works nicely on macOS too:

```
ruby -e "Dir['*'].each { |p| File.rename(p, p.downcase) }"
```

Comment: This is especially nice since Ruby ships with macOS.

Comment: Most useful thing I've seen thIs year so far.

Answer (score 4):

```
for f in `find -depth`; do mv ${f} ${f,,} ; done
```

`find -depth` prints each file and directory, with a directory's contents printed before the directory itself. `${f,,}` lowercases the file name.

Comment: This doesn't work: it renames a directory before it operates on the contents, such that the later attempt on the contents fails.

Comment: Adding `-depth` fixes that! This is a really quick solution, but of course without using the `-print0` option to find, it is not the most reliable

Comment: @jpaugh No it does not. It will try to rename ./FOO/BAR to ./foo/bar, but ./foo does not exist yet at that time.

Answer (score 3):

This is a small shell script that does what you requested:

```
root_directory="${1?-please specify parent directory}"
do_it () {
    awk '{ lc= tolower($0); if (lc != $0) print "mv \""  $0 "\" \"" lc "\"" }' | sh
}
# first the folders
find "$root_directory" -depth -type d | do_it
find "$root_directory" ! -type d | do_it
```

Note the -depth action in the first find.

Comment: The only thing that worked on a Mac from the whole thread. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3):

Use [typeset](https://helpmanual.io/builtin/typeset/):

```
typeset -l new        # Always lowercase
find $topPoint |      # Not using xargs to make this more readable
  while read old
  do new="$old"       # $new is a lowercase version of $old
     mv "$old" "$new" # Quotes for those annoying embedded spaces
  done
```

On Windows, emulations, like [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633), may fail because Windows isn't case-sensitive under the hood. For those, add a step that `mv`'s the file to another name first, like "$old.tmp", and then to `$new`.

Answer (score 2):

In OS X, `mv -f` shows "same file" error, so I rename twice:

```
for i in `find . -name "*" -type f |grep -e "[A-Z]"`; do j=`echo $i | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sed s/\-1$//`; mv $i $i-1; mv $i-1 $j; done
```

Answer (score 2):

With MacOS,

Install the `rename` package,

```
brew install rename
```

Use,

```
find . -iname "*.py" -type f | xargs -I% rename -c -f  "%"
```

This command find all the files with a `*.py` extension and converts the filenames to lower case.

```
`f` - forces a rename
```

For example,

```
$ find . -iname "*.py" -type f
./sample/Sample_File.py
./sample_file.py
$ find . -iname "*.py" -type f | xargs -I% rename -c -f  "%"
$ find . -iname "*.py" -type f
./sample/sample_file.py
./sample_file.py
```

Comment: Why did you use `-I` option for `xargs` here?

Comment: The `- I` flag is not mandatory. It is used when we execute multiple commands with `xargs`. 

Here is an example of using multiple commands with `xargs`

`cat foo.txt | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo %; mkdir %'`

You can run without `-I` like `find . -iname "*.py" -type f | xargs -I% rename -c -f  "%"`

Answer (score 2):

**Lengthy But *"Works With No Surprises & No Installations"***

This script **handles filenames with spaces, quotes, other *unusual* characters and Unicode, works on case insensitive filesystems and most Unix-y environments** that have bash and awk installed (i.e. almost all). It also reports collisions if any (leaving the filename in uppercase) and of course renames both files & directories and works recursively. Finally it's highly adaptable: you can tweak the find command to target the files/dirs you wish and you can tweak awk to do other name manipulations. Note that by "handles Unicode" I mean that it will indeed convert their case (not ignore them like answers that use `tr`).

```
# adapt the following command _IF_ you want to deal with specific files/dirs
find . -depth -mindepth 1 -exec bash -c '
  for file do
    # adapt the awk command if you wish to rename to something other than lowercase
    newname=$(dirname "$file")/$(basename "$file" | awk "{print tolower(\$0)}")
    if [ "$file" != "$newname" ] ; then
        # the extra step with the temp filename is for case-insensitive filesystems
        if [ ! -e "$newname" ] && [ ! -e "$newname.lcrnm.tmp" ] ; then
           mv -T "$file" "$newname.lcrnm.tmp" && mv -T "$newname.lcrnm.tmp" "$newname" 
        else
           echo "ERROR: Name already exists: $newname"
        fi
    fi    
  done
' sh {} +
```

---

**References**

My script is based on these excellent answers:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names

[How to convert a string to lower case in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash)

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions here worked for me because I was on a system that didn't have access to the perl rename script, plus some of the files included spaces. However, I found a variant that works:

```
find . -depth -exec sh -c '
    t=${0%/*}/$(printf %s "${0##*/}" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]");
    [ "$t" = "$0" ] || mv -i "$0" "$t"
' {} \;
```

Credit goes to "Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'", see [this answer on the similar question "change entire directory tree to lower-case names" on the Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20232/266760).

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this on a Cygwin setup on Windows 7 and found that I got syntax errors with the suggestions from above that I tried (though I may have missed a working option). However, this solution straight from [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1336909) worked out of the can :-)

```
ls | while read upName; do loName=`echo "${upName}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`; mv "$upName" "$loName"; done
```

(NB: I had previously replaced whitespace with underscores using:

```
for f in *\ *; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done
```

)

Answer (score 1):

#### Slugify Rename (regex)

It is not exactly what the OP asked for, but what I was hoping to find on this page:

A "slugify" version for renaming files so they are similar to URLs (i.e. only include alphanumeric, dots, and dashes):

```
rename "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]+/-/g" filename
```

Comment: "not exactly"?  this is not at all what the OP asked for

Answer (score 1):

I would reach for Python in this situation, to avoid optimistically assuming paths without spaces or slashes. I've also found that `python2` tends to be installed in more places than `rename`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys, os

def rename_dir(directory):
  print('DEBUG: rename('+directory+')')

  # Rename current directory if needed
  os.rename(directory, directory.lower())
  directory = directory.lower()

  # Rename children
  for fn in os.listdir(directory):
    path = os.path.join(directory, fn)
    os.rename(path, path.lower())
    path = path.lower()

    # Rename children within, if this child is a directory
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        rename_dir(path)

# Run program, using the first argument passed to this Python script as the name of the folder
rename_dir(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Talk about making it complicated... just do .. rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *

Comment: @Stephen, that assumes you have admin access to install rename. I frequently need to munge data on systems on which I do not have the ability to install other software. In recent Ubuntus, this is only installed if perl is present.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/), you can install [`rename`](https://fossies.org/linux/privat/old/rename-1.3.tar.gz/)) package from [`AUR`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rename) that provides the `renamexm` command as `/usr/bin/renamexm` executable and [a manual page](https://fossies.org/linux/rename/rename.1) along with it.

It is a really powerful tool to quickly rename files and directories.

#### Convert to lowercase

```
rename -l Developers.mp3 # or --lowcase
```

#### Convert to UPPER case

```
rename -u developers.mp3 # or --upcase, long option
```

#### Other options

```
-R --recursive # directory and its children

-t --test # Dry run, output but don't rename

-o --owner # Change file owner as well to user specified

-v --verbose # Output what file is renamed and its new name

-s/str/str2 # Substitute string on pattern

--yes # Confirm all actions
```

You can fetch the sample *Developers.mp3* file from [here](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/), if needed ;)

Comment: rename from `brew` on macOS has `-l` bound to creating a symlink, and `-c` to converting to lowercase, so watch out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the one-liners can be simplified:

`for f in **/*; do mv "$f" "${f:l}"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Using bash, without `rename`:

```
find . -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0,,}' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

**First Step**

on MacOS:

```bash
brew install rename
```

on linux:

```bash
sudo install rename
```

**Second Step**

```bash
find . -depth -execdir rename -f 'y/A-Z/a-z/' {} \;
```

**Explain**

`find . -depth`: Ensures that the directories are processed in a depth-first manner. It's important to avoid issues when renaming parent directories before their children.

```bash
$ tree -L 3                  
.
└── ACB
    ├── HUS
    └── TEXT.AA

$ find .
.
./ACB
./ACB/TEXT.AA
./ACB/HUS

$ find . -depth                                      
./ACB/TEXT.AA
./ACB/HUS
./ACB
.
```

`-execdir rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' {} \;`: Executes the rename command with the Perl expression 'y/A-Z/a-z/'. The `{}` is a placeholder for the directory name, and `\;` marks the end of the `-execdir` option.

```bash
$ find . -depth -execdir rename -f 'y/A-Z/a-z/' {} \;
# success
$ find .
.
./acb
./acb/text.aa
./acb/hus
```

Answer (score 0):

```
( find YOURDIR -type d | sort -r;
  find yourdir -type f ) |
grep -v /CVS | grep -v /SVN |
while read f; do mv -v $f `echo $f | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`; done
```

First rename the directories bottom up *sort -r* (where -depth is not available), then the files.
Then *grep -v /CVS* instead of *find ...-prune* because it's simpler.
For large directories, *for f in ...* can overflow some shell buffers.
Use *find ... | while read* to avoid that.

And yes, this will clobber files which differ only in case...

Comment: First: `find YOURDIR -type d | sort -r` is too much trouble. You want `find YOURDIR -depth -type d`.  
Second, the `find -type f` MUST run after the directories have been renamed.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -depth -name '*[A-Z]*'|sed -n 's/\(.*\/\)\(.*\)/mv -n -v -T \1\2 \1\L\2/p'|sh
```

I haven't tried the more elaborate scripts mentioned here, but none of the single commandline versions worked for me on my Synology NAS. `rename` is not available, and many of the variations of `find` fail because it seems to stick to the older name of the already renamed path (eg, if it finds `./FOO` followed by `./FOO/BAR`, renaming `./FOO` to `./foo` will still continue to list `./FOO/BAR` even though that path is no longer valid). Above command worked for me without any issues.

What follows is an explanation of each part of the command:

---

```
find . -depth -name '*[A-Z]*'
```

This will find any file from the current directory (change `.` to whatever directory you want to process), using a depth-first search (eg., it will list `./foo/bar` before `./foo`), but only for files that contain an uppercase character. The `-name` filter only applies to the base file name, not the full path. So this will list `./FOO/BAR` but not `./FOO/bar`. This is ok, as we don't want to rename `./FOO/bar`. We want to rename `./FOO` though, but that one is listed later on (this is why `-depth` is important).

This comand in itself is particularly useful to finding the files that you want to rename in the first place. Use this after the complete rename command to search for files that still haven't been replaced because of file name collisions or errors.

---

```
sed -n 's/\(.*\/\)\(.*\)/mv -n -v -T \1\2 \1\L\2/p'
```

This part reads the files outputted by `find` and formats them in a `mv` command using a regular expression. The `-n` option stops `sed` from printing the input, and the `p` command in the search-and-replace regex outputs the replaced text.

The regex itself consists of two captures: the part up until the last / (which is the directory of the file), and the filename itself. The directory is left intact, but the filename is transformed to lowercase. So, if `find` outputs `./FOO/BAR`, it will become `mv -n -v -T ./FOO/BAR ./FOO/bar`. The `-n` option of `mv` makes sure existing lowercase files are not overwritten. The `-v` option makes `mv` output every change that it makes (or doesn't make - if `./FOO/bar` already exists, it outputs something like `./FOO/BAR -> ./FOO/BAR`, noting that no change has been made). The `-T` is very important here - it treats the target file as a directory. This will make sure that `./FOO/BAR` isn't moved into `./FOO/bar` if that directory happens to exist.

Use this together with `find` to generate a list of commands that will be executed (handy to verify what will be done without actually doing it)

---

```
sh
```

This pretty self-explanatory. It routes all the generated `mv` commands to the shell interpreter. You can replace it with `bash` or any shell of your liking.