# How to convert a string to lower case in Bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, lowercase

Is there a way in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) to convert a string into a lower case string?

For example, if I have:

```
a="Hi all"
```

I want to convert it to:

```
"hi all"
```

Comment: **See also**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392189/

Answer (score 2999, accepted):

There are various ways:

#### [POSIX standard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)

##### [tr](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29)

```
$ echo "$a" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
hi all
```

##### [AWK](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)

```
$ echo "$a" | awk '{print tolower($0)}'
hi all
```

### Non-POSIX

You may run into portability issues with the following examples:

##### [Bash 4.0](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)

```
$ echo "${a,,}"
hi all
```

##### [sed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)

```
$ echo "$a" | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/'
hi all
# this also works:
$ sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' <<< "$a"
hi all
```

##### [Perl](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)

```
$ echo "$a" | perl -ne 'print lc'
hi all
```

##### [Bash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)

```
lc(){
    case "$1" in
        [A-Z])
        n=$(printf "%d" "'$1")
        n=$((n+32))
        printf \\$(printf "%o" "$n")
        ;;
        *)
        printf "%s" "$1"
        ;;
    esac
}
word="I Love Bash"
for((i=0;i<${#word};i++))
do
    ch="${word:$i:1}"
    lc "$ch"
done
```

Note: YMMV on this one. Doesn't work for me (GNU bash version 4.2.46 and 4.0.33 (and same behaviour 2.05b.0 but `nocasematch`  is not implemented)) even with using `shopt -u nocasematch;`. Unsetting that `nocasematch` causes `[[ "fooBaR" == "FOObar" ]]` to match OK BUT inside case weirdly `[b-z]` are incorrectly matched by `[A-Z]`. Bash is confused by the double-negative ("unsetting nocasematch")! :-)

Comment: Am I missing something, or does your last example (in Bash) actually do something completely different? It works for "ABX", but if you instead make `word="Hi All"` like the other examples, it returns `ha`, not `hi all`. It only works for the capitalized letters and skips the already-lowercased letters.

Comment: Note that only the `tr` and `awk` examples are specified in the POSIX standard.

Comment: `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` will use the current locale to determine uppercase/lowercase equivalents, so it'll work with locales that use letters with diacritical marks.

Comment: How does one get the output into a new variable?  Ie say I want the lowercased string into a new variable?

Comment: @Adam: `b="$(echo $a | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')"`

Comment: @RichardHansen My "tr (GNU coreutils) 8.21" on FreeBSD doesn't work for UTF-8 locales. Neither does tr on our default Ubuntu 12.04 install.

Comment: @Ark-kun: Works OK on my Ubuntu 12.04 system:  `(export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8; echo FOO | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')` prints `foo`

Comment: @RichardHansen First 128 ASCII chars always work. It's all other thousands of character that don't. On FreeBSD 9 `tr` works properly. On Ubuntu 12.04 `tr` doesn't work properly with non-latin characters in utf-8 locales: `$ echo -e 'FOO\xC0\xD0\xE0\xF0' | iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 | LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8 tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | iconv -f utf-8`
`fooАРар` (doesn't work);`$ echo -e 'FOO\xC0\xD0\xE0\xF0' | LC_ALL=ru_RU.CP1251 tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
`fooарар` (works)

Comment: @Ark-kun: I recommend creating a new question about this.

Comment: @Adam again: `b="${a,,}"` for Bash4 is more efficient than `b="$(echo ${a,,})"`.  Both are a bit different, as with `a="H   W"` (3 spaces between H and W) the first sets `b="h   w"` (3 spaces), the latter `b="h w"` (1 space) (sorry, SO removes multiple spaces in examples)

Comment: How do I do it in `sh` (aka `dash`)

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.10 `awk '{print tolower($0)}'` nicely converts locale-dependent characters, but those fail: `${a,,}` `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' `.

Comment: Am I missing something here? I see lots of commands that print out the lowercase version of the variable, but none that actually change the value.

Comment: @AaronF That's how shell is often used:  The output of a shell command on stdout is its "result" (its exit code is rather its exception state).  To store that "result", use the `a=$(…)` notation mentioned above.

Comment: it would be better if the examples were updated to assign to a variable rather than echo them.

Comment: reduced pipe awk solution:  $(awk 'END { print tolower(s); }' s="$a" /dev/null)

Comment: Alternatively, 

b=`echo $a | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`

has always worked for me.
Enclosing marks are the back tics, the key just below Esc key.

Comment: @jangosteve, You were right about the Bash example, it is fixed now. Only uppercase chars were being processed and all else was discarded. I have added a "passthru" printf for the other chars and changed the example to one with upper and lower chars and spaces. BTW for uppercase, just change +32 to -32.

Comment: @AlexanderMills, `tr` is standardized -- **all** POSIX systems are required to include it. Ubuntu absolutely does.

Comment: `echo "$a"` is prone to failure, e.g. if `a="-n"`. Use `printf` to be safe: `result="$(printf "%s" "$a" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"`

Comment: Could you please edit the post and add the differences among these approaches?

Comment: The performance of this approach for Bash pre-4.0 is pretty bad, please see my answer for metrics.

Comment: how come `awk` solution is POSIX based but `sed` is not?

Comment: It is better to use gawk which properly handles UTF8-encoded characters (and different languages charset). 'Awk tolower' will fail on something like "ЛШТШФУМ АЩЬФ".

Comment: Note that the `tr` solution will not convert umlauts such as `Ä` - `ä`.

Comment: Please edit to add `fish shell` solution: `string lower $a`

Comment: `echo "$a" |` will not work when `a` is `-n` `-e` or similar on specific implementation. Please use `printf "%s\n" "$a" |`

Comment: The `sed` version doesn't work on OSX, for the record. Perhaps unsurprisingly since all commandline utilities are as old as the hills there....

Comment: The first TR solution worked perfectly for me thanks!

Answer (score 567):

In Bash 4:

To lowercase

```
$ string="A FEW WORDS"
$ echo "${string,}"
a FEW WORDS
$ echo "${string,,}"
a few words
$ echo "${string,,[AEIUO]}"
a FeW WoRDS

$ string="A Few Words"
$ declare -l string
$ string=$string; echo "$string"
a few words
```

To uppercase

```
$ string="a few words"
$ echo "${string^}"
A few words
$ echo "${string^^}"
A FEW WORDS
$ echo "${string^^[aeiou]}"
A fEw wOrds

$ string="A Few Words"
$ declare -u string
$ string=$string; echo "$string"
A FEW WORDS
```

Toggle (undocumented, but optionally configurable at compile time)

```
$ string="A Few Words"
$ echo "${string~~}"
a fEW wORDS
$ string="A FEW WORDS"
$ echo "${string~}"
a FEW WORDS
$ string="a few words"
$ echo "${string~}"
A few words
```

Capitalize (undocumented, but optionally configurable at compile time)

```
$ string="a few words"
$ declare -c string
$ string=$string
$ echo "$string"
A few words
```

Title case:

```
$ string="a few words"
$ string=($string)
$ string="${string[@]^}"
$ echo "$string"
A Few Words

$ declare -c string
$ string=(a few words)
$ echo "${string[@]}"
A Few Words

$ string="a FeW WOrdS"
$ string=${string,,}
$ string=${string~}
$ echo "$string"
A few words
```

To turn off a `declare` attribute, use `+`. For example, `declare +c string`. This affects subsequent assignments and not the current value.

The `declare` options change the attribute of the variable, but not the contents. The reassignments in my examples update the contents to show the changes.

**Edit:**

Added "toggle first character by word" (`${var~}`) as suggested by **ghostdog74**.

**Edit:** Corrected tilde behavior to match Bash 4.3.

Comment: Quite bizzare, "^^" and ",," operators don't work on non-ASCII characters but "~~" does... So `string="łódź"; echo ${string~~}` will return "ŁÓDŹ", but `echo ${string^^}` returns "łóDź". Even in `LC_ALL=pl_PL.utf-8`. That's using bash 4.2.24.

Comment: @HubertKario: That's weird. It's the same for me in Bash 4.0.33 with the same string in `en_US.UTF-8`. It's a bug and I've reported it.

Comment: @HubertKario: Try `echo "$string" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`. It will probably exhibit the same failure. So the problem is at least partly not Bash's.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Yeah, I've noticed that too (see comment to Shuvalov answer). I'd just say, "this stuff is only for ASCII", but then it's the "~~" operator that does work, so it's not like the code and translation tables aren't already there...

Comment: @HubertKario: The Bash maintainer has [acknowledged](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/gnu.bash.bug/K4xWT6V7es0) the bug and stated that it will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: The following capitalise only the first letter of the sentence (even if there are several words) `echo ${string^}` which is quite usefull if you are writing a story in Bash (tested on version 4.1.2 on RHEL6.5).

Comment: @vaxquis: I'm reverting your changes, because the `declare` doesn't, by itself, change the contents of the variable. The reassignment is necessary. The last reassignment converts a scalar to an array. It could have been directly assigned as an array, but the reassignment illustrates how a scalar can be title cased.

Comment: @vaxquis: I've added a statement to that effect. In the future, you shouldn't edit a post without first testing your changes.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson believe me or not, in my script it worked even without the reassignment... maybe because it was used in a loop, dunno? check if for yourself: https://pastebin.com/ZG52LBHf

Comment: @vaxquis: First make sure the attribute is cleared: `declare +u w`, then run this loop (equivalent to yours): `for w in word1 word2 word3 word4; do declare -u w; echo "$w"; done` - "word1" is output as-is while the others are uppercased. If you run the loop again without clearing the attribute, all the output words are uppercased. As I said in my answer, the attribute is applied to the value on assignment rather than at declaration. In fact, unless you need to change an attribute with each iteration of the loop, you should put the declaration before the loop since it's unnecessary to...

Comment: ... set the attribute again once it's set. `declare -u w; for w in word1 word2 word3 word4; do echo "$w"; done`

Answer (score 164):

```
echo "Hi All" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"
```

Comment: @RichardHansen: `tr` doesn't work for me for non-ACII characters. I do have correct locale set and locale files generated. Have any idea what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: This worked on Windows/Msys. Some of the other suggestions did not.

Comment: Why is `[:upper:]` needed?

Comment: The same question why `[:upper:]` is needed.

Comment: @mgutt and MaXi32: It specifies to translate characters from upper to lower.

Comment: `tr` needs two arguments - the list of `from` characters, and the list of `to` characters. `[:upper:]` is a character class, which is just a fancy way of saying it's a list of all uppercase characters (though there's some question over whether `tr` properly considers Unicode rather than just ASCII). `[:lower:]`, then, is the list of all lowercase characters. `tr` then takes both lists and `tr`anslates characters in the `from` list to the corresponding characters in the `to` list. So `[:upper:]` is needed so `tr` knows what it's supposed to change, while `[:lower:]` tells it what to change to.

Comment: @DanHunsaker good answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 115):

#### [tr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29):

```
a="$(tr [A-Z] [a-z] <<< "$a")"
```

#### [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
{ print tolower($0) }
```

#### [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed):

```
y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/
```

Comment: +1 `a="$(tr [A-Z] [a-z] <<< "$a")"` looks easiest to me. I am still a beginner...

Comment: I strongly recommend the `sed` solution; I've been working in an environment that for some reason doesn't have `tr` but I've yet to find a system without `sed`, plus a lot of the time I want to do this I've just done something else in `sed` anyway so can chain the commands together into a single (long) statement.

Comment: The bracket expressions should be quoted. In `tr [A-Z] [a-z] A`, the shell may perform filename expansion if there are filenames consisting of a single letter or *nullgob* is set. `tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" A` will behave properly.

Comment: @Haravikk no `tr`? What kind of excuse for a system is that? There's even Windows builds. And it's so simple a shell script could polyfill it (but you might want to take a look into Busybox for that system).

Comment: @CamiloMartin it's a BusyBox system where I'm having that problem, specifically Synology NASes, but I've encountered it on a few other systems too. I've been doing a lot of cross-platform shell scripting lately, and with the requirement that nothing extra be installed it makes things very tricky! However I've yet to encounter a system without `sed`

Comment: @Haravikk Huh, I would expect `sed` to be more likely to be missing than `tr`, being much more capable and feature-rich. Does it have `gcc` or something? Maybe compiling busybox from source could make your life easier (I don't have any idea of how easy/hard working with such a device might be).

Comment: Note that `tr [A-Z] [a-z]` is incorrect in almost all locales. for example, in the `en-US` locale, `A-Z` is actually the interval `AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHh...XxYyZ`.

Comment: I think the brackets in `tr` are useless and can be removed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51983/how-to-uppercase-the-command-line-argument#comment801846_344791

Comment: It is better to use gawk which properly handles UTF8-encoded characters (and different languages charset). 'Awk tolower' will fail on something like "ЛШТШФУМ АЩЬФ".

Answer (score 100):

I know this is an oldish post but I made this answer for another site so I thought I'd post it up here:

**UPPER -> lower**:
use python:

```
b=`echo "print '$a'.lower()" | python`
```

Or Ruby:

```
b=`echo "print '$a'.downcase" | ruby`
```

Or Perl:

```
b=`perl -e "print lc('$a');"`
```

Or PHP:

```
b=`php -r "print strtolower('$a');"`
```

Or Awk:

```
b=`echo "$a" | awk '{ print tolower($1) }'`
```

Or Sed:

```
b=`echo "$a" | sed 's/./\L&/g'`
```

Or Bash 4:

```
b=${a,,}
```

Or NodeJS:

```
b=`node -p "\"$a\".toLowerCase()"`
```

You could also use `dd`:

```
b=`echo "$a" | dd  conv=lcase 2> /dev/null`
```

**lower -> UPPER**:

use python:

```
b=`echo "print '$a'.upper()" | python`
```

Or Ruby:

```
b=`echo "print '$a'.upcase" | ruby`
```

Or Perl:

```
b=`perl -e "print uc('$a');"`
```

Or PHP:

```
b=`php -r "print strtoupper('$a');"`
```

Or Awk:

```
b=`echo "$a" | awk '{ print toupper($1) }'`
```

Or Sed:

```
b=`echo "$a" | sed 's/./\U&/g'`
```

Or Bash 4:

```
b=${a^^}
```

Or NodeJS:

```
b=`node -p "\"$a\".toUpperCase()"`
```

You could also use `dd`:

```
b=`echo "$a" | dd  conv=ucase 2> /dev/null`
```

Also when you say 'shell' I'm assuming you mean `bash` but if you can use `zsh` it's as easy as

```
b=$a:l
```

for lower case and

```
b=$a:u
```

for upper case.

Comment: @JESii both work for me upper -> lower and lower-> upper. I'm using sed 4.2.2 and Bash 4.3.42(1) on 64bit Debian Stretch.

Comment: Hi, @nettux443... I just tried the bash operation again and it still fails for me with the error message "bad substitution". I'm on OSX using homebrew's bash: GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0)

Comment: **Do not use!** All of the examples which generate a script are extremely brittle; if the value of `a` contains a single quote, you have not only broken behavior, but a serious security problem.

Comment: I like the sed solution the most, since sed is always ubiquitous.

Comment: I prefer using the dd solution. Please note that you need to be root to get it working

Comment: Node alternative: `node -p "\"$a\".toLowerCase()" `

Comment: I tried `sed 's/./\L&/g'` in zsh, but the output is full of Ls...

Answer (score 89):

[Bash 5.1](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) provides a straight forward way to do this with the `L` parameter transformation:

```
${var@L}
```

So for example you can say:

```bash
v="heLLo"
echo "${v@L}"
# hello
```

---

You can also do uppercase with `U`:

```bash
v="hello"
echo "${v@U}"
# HELLO
```

And uppercase the first letter with `u`:

```bash
v="hello"
echo "${v@u}"
# Hello
```

Comment: Absolutely deserves more upvotes than it currently has!

Comment: @Umlin it is a brand new feature, so it is normal that didn't get much attention yet.

Comment: I can't use this yet, but glad to know it's a thing!

Comment: Oh weird. I wonder why they introduced this when `${v^^}` and `${v,,}` already exist.

Answer (score 36):

In zsh:

```
echo $a:u
```

Gotta love zsh!

Comment: or $a:l for lower case conversion

Comment: Add one more case: `echo ${(C)a} #Upcase the first char only`

Comment: @biocyberman is there a way to lowercase the first char only?

Comment: Not something I know of. You can read about available flags here: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags

Comment: @karlahrnndz Actually you can do something like thins: `${a:0:1:l}${a:1}` to lowercase only the first character.

Answer (score 20):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*/\L&/'
```

Example:

```
$ foo="Some STRIng";
$ foo=$(echo "$foo" | sed 's/.*/\L&/')
$ echo "$foo"
some string
```

Answer (score 18):

Pre Bash 4.0

**Bash Lower the Case of a string and assign to variable**

```
VARIABLE=$(echo "$VARIABLE" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') 

echo "$VARIABLE"
```

Comment: No need for `echo` and pipes: use `$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<"$VARIABLE")`

Comment: @Tino The here string is also not portable back to really old versions of Bash; I believe it was introduced in v3.

Comment: @tripleee You are right, it was introduced in bash-2.05b - however that's the oldest bash I was able to find on my systems

Answer (score 14):

For the Bash command line and depending on locale and international letters, this might work (assembled from the answers from others):

```sh
$ echo "ABCÆØÅ" | python -c "print(open(0).read().lower())"
abcæøå
$ echo "ABCÆØÅ" | sed 's/./\L&/g'
abcæøå
$ export a="ABCÆØÅ" | echo "${a,,}"
abcæøå
```

Whereas these variations might NOT work:

```sh
$ echo "ABCÆØÅ" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"
abcÆØÅ
$ echo "ABCÆØÅ" | awk '{print tolower($1)}'
abcÆØÅ
$ echo "ABCÆØÅ" | perl -ne 'print lc'
abcÆØÅ
$ echo 'ABCÆØÅ' | dd conv=lcase 2> /dev/null
abcÆØÅ
```

Comment: Does `echo "ABCÆØÅ" | ruby -pe '$_.downcase!'` work correctly?

Comment: Yes. The Ruby version also works with my setup.

Comment: Probably not BSD sed.

Answer (score 14):

```
[dev@localhost ~]$ TEST=STRESS2
[dev@localhost ~]$ echo ${TEST,,}
stress2
```

Answer (score 13):

You can try this

```
s="Hello World!" 

echo $s  # Hello World!

a=${s,,}
echo $a  # hello world!

b=${s^^}
echo $b  # HELLO WORLD!
```

[image]

ref : http://wiki.workassis.com/shell-script-convert-text-to-lowercase-and-uppercase/

Comment: great! Was about to make an answer like this. Many answers adding lots of unneeded info

Answer (score 13):

Simple way

```
echo "Hi all" | awk '{ print tolower($0); }'
```

Comment: It is better to use gawk which properly handles UTF8-encoded characters (and different languages charset). 'Awk tolower' will fail on something like "ЛШТШФУМ АЩЬФ".

Comment: the awk available on macOS 11.6 works flawlessly: `echo 'Đêm lưu trú năm nay' | awk '{ print tolower($0); }'` => `đêm lưu trú năm nay`, and `echo 'ЛШТШФУМ АЩЬФ' | awk '{ print tolower($0); }'` => `лштшфум ащьф`

Answer (score 12):

For a standard shell (without bashisms) using only builtins:

```
uppers=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
lowers=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

lc(){ #usage: lc "SOME STRING" -> "some string"
    i=0
    while ([ $i -lt ${#1} ]) do
        CUR=${1:$i:1}
        case $uppers in
            *$CUR*)CUR=${uppers%$CUR*};OUTPUT="${OUTPUT}${lowers:${#CUR}:1}";;
            *)OUTPUT="${OUTPUT}$CUR";;
        esac
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    echo "${OUTPUT}"
}
```

And for upper case:

```
uc(){ #usage: uc "some string" -> "SOME STRING"
    i=0
    while ([ $i -lt ${#1} ]) do
        CUR=${1:$i:1}
        case $lowers in
            *$CUR*)CUR=${lowers%$CUR*};OUTPUT="${OUTPUT}${uppers:${#CUR}:1}";;
            *)OUTPUT="${OUTPUT}$CUR";;
        esac
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    echo "${OUTPUT}"
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you didn't let some bashism in this script, as it's not portable on FreeBSD sh: ${1:$...}: Bad substitution

Comment: Indeed; substrings with `${var:1:1}` are a Bashism.

Comment: This approach has pretty bad performance metrics.  See my answer for metrics.

Answer (score 12):

In bash 4 you can use typeset

Example:

```
A="HELLO WORLD"
typeset -l A=$A
```

Comment: Ah, we poor macOS users, it's 2020 and Apple has dropped support for `bash` which is 'stuck' at 3.2.57(1)...

(Note: aye, I'm aware we can always install a more recent `bash` from `homebrew`...)

Answer (score 9):

From the `bash` manpage:

> ${parameter^pattern}
>
> ${parameter^^pattern}
>
> ${parameter,pattern}
>
> ${parameter,,pattern}
>
> **Case modification**. This expansion modifies the case of alphabetic characters in *parameter*. The *pattern* is expanded to produce a
> pattern just as in pathname expansion. Each character in the expanded
> value of *parameter* is tested against *pattern*, and, if it matches
> the pattern, its case is converted. The pattern should not attempt to
> match more than one character. The **^** operator converts lowercase
> letters matching *pattern* to uppercase; the **,** operator converts
> matching uppercase letters to lowercase. The **^^** and **,,**
> expansions convert each matched character in the expanded value; the
> **^** and **,** expansions match and convert only the first character in the expanded value. If *pattern* is omitted, it is treated like a
> **?**, which matches every character. If *parameter* is **@** or *****, the case modification operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If
> *parameter* is an array variable subscripted with **@** or *****, the case modification operation is applied to each member of the array in
> turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Answer (score 7):

### Regular expression

I would like to take credit for the command I wish to share but the truth is I obtained it for my own use from http://commandlinefu.com. It has the advantage that if you `cd` to any directory within your own home folder that is it will change all files and folders to lower case recursively please use with caution. It is a brilliant command line fix and especially useful for those multitudes of albums you have stored on your drive.

```
find . -depth -exec rename 's/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\L$2/' {} \;
```

You can specify a directory in place of the dot(.) after the find which denotes current directory or full path.

I hope this solution proves useful the one thing this command does not do is replace spaces with underscores - oh well another time perhaps.

Comment: This didn't work for me for whatever reason, though it looks fine. I did get this to work as an alternative though:

find . -exec /bin/bash -c 'mv {} \`tr [A-Z] [a-z] <<< {}\`' \;

Comment: This needs `prename` from `perl`: `dpkg -S "$(readlink -e /usr/bin/rename)"` gives `perl: /usr/bin/prename`

Answer (score 6):

Many answers using external programs, which is not really using `Bash`.

If you know you will have Bash4 available you should really just use the `${VAR,,}` notation (it is easy and cool). For Bash before 4 (My Mac still uses Bash 3.2 for example). I used the corrected version of @ghostdog74 's answer to create a more portable version.

One you can call `lowercase 'my STRING'` and get a lowercase version. I read comments about setting the result to a var, but that is not really portable in `Bash`, since we can't return strings. Printing it is the best solution. Easy to capture with something like `var="$(lowercase $str)"`.

**How this works**

The way this works is by getting the ASCII integer representation of each char with `printf` and then `adding 32` if `upper-to->lower`, or `subtracting 32` if `lower-to->upper`. Then use `printf` again to convert the number back to a char. From `'A' -to-> 'a'` we have a difference of 32 chars.

Using `printf` to explain:

```
$ printf "%d\n" "'a"
97
$ printf "%d\n" "'A"
65
```

`97 - 65 = 32`

And this is the working version with examples.
Please note the comments in the code, as they explain a lot of stuff:

```
#!/bin/bash

# lowerupper.sh

# Prints the lowercase version of a char
lowercaseChar(){
    case "$1" in
        [A-Z])
            n=$(printf "%d" "'$1")
            n=$((n+32))
            printf \\$(printf "%o" "$n")
            ;;
        *)
            printf "%s" "$1"
            ;;
    esac
}

# Prints the lowercase version of a sequence of strings
lowercase() {
    word="$@"
    for((i=0;i<${#word};i++)); do
        ch="${word:$i:1}"
        lowercaseChar "$ch"
    done
}

# Prints the uppercase version of a char
uppercaseChar(){
    case "$1" in
        [a-z])
            n=$(printf "%d" "'$1")
            n=$((n-32))
            printf \\$(printf "%o" "$n")
            ;;
        *)
            printf "%s" "$1"
            ;;
    esac
}

# Prints the uppercase version of a sequence of strings
uppercase() {
    word="$@"
    for((i=0;i<${#word};i++)); do
        ch="${word:$i:1}"
        uppercaseChar "$ch"
    done
}

# The functions will not add a new line, so use echo or
# append it if you want a new line after printing

# Printing stuff directly
lowercase "I AM the Walrus!"$'\n'
uppercase "I AM the Walrus!"$'\n'

echo "----------"

# Printing a var
str="A StRing WITH mixed sTUFF!"
lowercase "$str"$'\n'
uppercase "$str"$'\n'

echo "----------"

# Not quoting the var should also work, 
# since we use "$@" inside the functions
lowercase $str$'\n'
uppercase $str$'\n'

echo "----------"

# Assigning to a var
myLowerVar="$(lowercase $str)"
myUpperVar="$(uppercase $str)"
echo "myLowerVar: $myLowerVar"
echo "myUpperVar: $myUpperVar"

echo "----------"

# You can even do stuff like
if [[ 'option 2' = "$(lowercase 'OPTION 2')" ]]; then
    echo "Fine! All the same!"
else
    echo "Ops! Not the same!"
fi

exit 0
```

And the results after running this:

```
$ ./lowerupper.sh 
i am the walrus!
I AM THE WALRUS!
----------
a string with mixed stuff!
A STRING WITH MIXED STUFF!
----------
a string with mixed stuff!
A STRING WITH MIXED STUFF!
----------
myLowerVar: a string with mixed stuff!
myUpperVar: A STRING WITH MIXED STUFF!
----------
Fine! All the same!
```

**This should only work for ASCII characters though**.

For me it is fine, since I know I will only pass ASCII chars to it.
I am using this for some case-insensitive CLI options, for example.

Comment: i use a similar trick to `97 - 65 = 32` for determining the `ASCII` offset for first 52 letters within base64 : `3^4 - 2^4 = 65`, `3^4 + 2^4 = 97`

Answer (score 6):

Converting case is done for alphabets only. So, this should work neatly.

I am focusing on converting alphabets between a-z from upper case to lower case. Any other characters should just be printed in stdout as it is...

Converts the all text in path/to/file/filename within a-z range to A-Z

For converting lower case to upper case

```
cat path/to/file/filename | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
```

For converting from upper case to lower case

```
cat path/to/file/filename | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'
```

For example,

filename:

```
my name is xyz
```

gets converted to:

```
MY NAME IS XYZ
```

Example 2:

```
echo "my name is 123 karthik" | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
# Output:
# MY NAME IS 123 KARTHIK
```

Example 3:

```
echo "my name is 123 &&^&& #@$#@%%& kAR2~thik" | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
# Output:
# MY NAME IS 123 &&^&& #@0@%%& KAR2~THIK
```

Answer (score 6):

For Bash3.2.+ | Mac:

```
read -p 'What is your email? ' email
email=$(echo $email | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
email="$email"
echo $email
```

Answer (score 4):

If using v4, this is [baked-in](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#case_modification).  If not, here is a **simple, widely applicable** solution.  Other answers (and comments) on this thread were quite helpful in creating the code below.

```
# Like echo, but converts to lowercase
echolcase () {
    tr [:upper:] [:lower:] <<< "${*}"
}

# Takes one arg by reference (var name) and makes it lowercase
lcase () { 
    eval "${1}"=\'$(echo ${!1//\'/"'\''"} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] )\'
}
```

*Notes:*

- Doing: `a="Hi All"` and then: `lcase a` will do the same thing as: `a=$( echolcase "Hi All" )`
- In the lcase function, using `${!1//\'/"'\''"}` instead of `${!1}` allows this to work even when the string has quotes.

Answer (score 4):

This is a far faster variation of [JaredTS486's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599178/111948) that uses native Bash capabilities (including Bash versions <4.0) to optimize his approach.

I've timed 1,000 iterations of this approach for a small string (25 characters) and a larger string (445 characters), both for lowercase and uppercase conversions.  Since the test strings are predominantly lowercase, conversions to lowercase are generally faster than to uppercase.

I've compared my approach with several other answers on this page that are compatible with Bash 3.2.  My approach is far more performant than most approaches documented here, and is even faster than `tr` in several cases.

Here are the timing results for 1,000 iterations of 25 characters:

- 0.46s for my approach to lowercase; 0.96s for uppercase
- 1.16s for [Orwellophile's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599178/111948) to lowercase; 1.59s for uppercase
- 3.67s for `tr` to lowercase; 3.81s for uppercase
- 11.12s for [ghostdog74's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2264537/111948) to lowercase; 31.41s for uppercase
- 26.25s for [technosaurus' approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8952274/111948) to lowercase; 26.21s for uppercase
- 25.06s for [JaredTS486's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34440970/111948) to lowercase; 27.04s for uppercase

Timing results for 1,000 iterations of 445 characters (consisting of the poem "The Robin" by Witter Bynner):

- 2s for my approach to lowercase; 12s for uppercase
- 4s for `tr` to lowercase; 4s for uppercase
- 20s for [Orwellophile's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599178/111948) to lowercase; 29s for uppercase
- 75s for [ghostdog74's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2264537/111948) approach to lowercase; 669s for uppercase.  It's interesting to note how dramatic the performance difference is between a test with predominant matches vs. a test with predominant misses
- 467s for [technosaurus' approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8952274/111948) to lowercase; 449s for uppercase
- 660s for [JaredTS486's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34440970/111948) to lowercase; 660s for uppercase.  It's interesting to note that this approach generated continuous page faults (memory swapping) in Bash

Solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u

declare LCS="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
declare UCS="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

function lcase()
{
  local TARGET="${1-}"
  local UCHAR=''
  local UOFFSET=''

  while [[ "${TARGET}" =~ ([A-Z]) ]]
  do
    UCHAR="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    UOFFSET="${UCS%%${UCHAR}*}"
    TARGET="${TARGET//${UCHAR}/${LCS:${#UOFFSET}:1}}"
  done

  echo -n "${TARGET}"
}

function ucase()
{
  local TARGET="${1-}"
  local LCHAR=''
  local LOFFSET=''

  while [[ "${TARGET}" =~ ([a-z]) ]]
  do
    LCHAR="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    LOFFSET="${LCS%%${LCHAR}*}"
    TARGET="${TARGET//${LCHAR}/${UCS:${#LOFFSET}:1}}"
  done

  echo -n "${TARGET}"
}
```

The approach is simple: while the input string has any remaining uppercase letters present, find the next one, and replace all instances of that letter with its lowercase variant.  Repeat until all uppercase letters are replaced.

Some performance characteristics of my solution:

1. Uses only shell builtin utilities, which avoids the overhead of invoking external binary utilities in a new process
2. Avoids sub-shells, which incur performance penalties
3. Uses shell mechanisms that are compiled and optimized for performance, such as global string replacement within variables, variable suffix trimming, and regex searching and matching.  These mechanisms are far faster than iterating manually through strings
4. Loops only the number of times required by the count of unique matching characters to be converted.  For example, converting a string that has three different uppercase characters to lowercase requires only 3 loop iterations.  For the preconfigured ASCII alphabet, the maximum number of loop iterations is 26
5. `UCS` and `LCS` can be augmented with additional characters

Comment: how am i supposed to use these function of yours with the pipe ? i pasted your code, verbatim, and it keeps exiting the shell without returning anything : `. ./testchgcase.bash ; pvE0 < "${m3t}" | ucase | ghead

[Process completed]`

Comment: @RARE Kpop Manifesto
You need to catch the piped data and call a function Add as the last line: lcase "$(cat)"

Answer (score 4):

so i attempted to perform some updated benchmarking using the consensus approach for each utility, but instead of repeating a tiny set many times, I ...

1. fed in a **`1.85 GB`** **`.txt`** file that's filled to the brim w/ multi-byte `Unicode` chars in `UTF-8` encoding,
2. via the `pipe` in order to equalize I/O aspect,
3. while also enforcing `LC_ALL=C` for all to ensure level playing field

————————————————————————————————————————

- Both `bsd-sed` and `gnu-sed` are rather mediocre, to put it *very* nicely.

  - I don't even know what `bsd-sed` was trying to do, as their `xxhash` doesn't match
- was `python3` trying to do Unicode letter-casing ?

  - (even though I already forced the locale setting `LC_ALL=C` )
- `tr` is the most extreme

  1. `gnu-tr` is, **by far**, the fastest among all
  2. `bsd-tr` utterly atrocious
- `perl5` is faster than any `awk` variant I have, unless you're okay with loading the whole file at once using `mawk2` in order to gain a tiny bit over `perl5` :

  ```
    2.935s mawk2 
  vs
    3.081s perl5
  ```
- within `awk`, `gnu-gawk` appears slowest among the 3 , `mawk 1.3.4` in the middle, and `mawk 1.9.9.6` fastest : more than 50% time savings over `gawk`

  . *(I didn't waste my time with the useless `macosx nawk`)*

.

```
     out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:03 [ 568MiB/s] [ 568MiB/s] [ <=> ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:03 [ 568MiB/s] [ 568MiB/s] [============>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C mawk2 '{ print tolower($_) }' FS='^$'; )  

mawk 1.9.9.6 (mawk2-beta)

3.07s user 0.66s system 111% cpu 3.348 total
85759a34df874966d096c6529dbfb9d5  stdin


     out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:06 [ 297MiB/s] [ 297MiB/s] [ <=> ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:06 [ 297MiB/s] [ 297MiB/s] [============>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C mawk '{ print tolower($_) }' FS='^$'; )  

 mawk 1.3.4

6.01s user 0.83s system 107% cpu 6.368 total
85759a34df874966d096c6529dbfb9d5  stdin

     out9: 23.8MiB 0:00:00 [ 238MiB/s] [ 238MiB/s] [ <=> ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:07 [ 244MiB/s] [ 244MiB/s] [============>] 100%            
     out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:07 [ 244MiB/s] [ 244MiB/s] [ <=>                             ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C gawk -be '{ print tolower($_) }' FS='^$';  

GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1) 

7.49s user 0.78s system 106% cpu 7.763 total
85759a34df874966d096c6529dbfb9d5  stdin


     out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:03 [ 616MiB/s] [ 616MiB/s] [ <=> ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:03 [ 617MiB/s] [ 617MiB/s] [============>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C perl -ne 'print lc'; )  

perl5 (revision 5 version 34 subversion 0)

2.70s user 0.85s system 115% cpu 3.081 total
85759a34df874966d096c6529dbfb9d5  stdin


     out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:32 [57.4MiB/s] [57.4MiB/s] [ <=> ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:32 [57.4MiB/s] [57.4MiB/s] [============>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C gsed 's/.*/\L&/'; )  # GNU-sed


gsed (GNU sed) 4.8

32.57s user 0.97s system 101% cpu 32.982 total
85759a34df874966d096c6529dbfb9d5  stdin


     out9: 1.86GiB 0:00:38 [49.7MiB/s] [49.7MiB/s] [ <=> ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:38 [49.4MiB/s] [49.4MiB/s] [============>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C sed 's/.*/\L&/'; )   # BSD-sed



37.94s user 0.86s system 101% cpu 38.318 total
d5e2d8487df1136db7c2334a238755c0  stdin



      in0:  313MiB 0:00:00 [3.06GiB/s] [3.06GiB/s] [=====>] 16% ETA 0:00:00
     out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:11 [ 166MiB/s] [ 166MiB/s] [ <=>]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:00 [3.31GiB/s] [3.31GiB/s] [============>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C python3 -c "print(open(0).read().lower())) 

Python 3.9.12 

9.04s user 2.18s system 98% cpu 11.403 total
7ddc0b5cbcfbbfac3c2b6da6731bd262  stdin

     out9: 2.51MiB 0:00:00 [25.1MiB/s] [25.1MiB/s] [ <=> ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:11 [ 171MiB/s] [ 171MiB/s] [============>] 100%            
     out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:11 [ 171MiB/s] [ 171MiB/s] [ <=> ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C ruby -pe '$_.downcase!'; )


ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]

10.46s user 1.23s system 105% cpu 11.073 total
85759a34df874966d096c6529dbfb9d5  stdin


      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:01 [1.01GiB/s] [1.01GiB/s] [============>] 100%            
     out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:01 [1.01GiB/s] [1.01GiB/s] [ <=> ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C gtr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'; )  # GNU-tr


gtr (GNU coreutils) 9.1

1.11s user 1.21s system 124% cpu 1.855 total
85759a34df874966d096c6529dbfb9d5  stdin


     out9: 1.85GiB 0:01:19 [23.7MiB/s] [23.7MiB/s] [ <=> ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:01:19 [23.7MiB/s] [23.7MiB/s] [============>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'; ) # BSD-tr

78.94s user 1.50s system 100% cpu 1:19.67 total
85759a34df874966d096c6529dbfb9d5  stdin


( time ( pvE0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C   gdd  conv=lcase ) | pvE9 )  | xxh128sum | lgp3; sleep 3; 
     out9: 0.00 B 0:00:01 [0.00 B/s] [0.00 B/s] [<=> ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:06 [ 295MiB/s] [ 295MiB/s] [============>] 100%            
     out9: 1.81GiB 0:00:06 [ 392MiB/s] [ 294MiB/s] [ <=>   ]
3874110+1 records in
3874110+1 records out
     out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:06 [ 295MiB/s] [ 295MiB/s] [ <=>  ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C gdd conv=lcase; )  # GNU-dd


gdd (coreutils) 9.1

1.93s user 4.35s system 97% cpu 6.413 total
85759a34df874966d096c6529dbfb9d5  stdin



%  ( time ( pvE0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C   dd  conv=lcase ) | pvE9 )  | xxh128sum | lgp3; sleep 3; 
     out9: 36.9MiB 0:00:00 [ 368MiB/s] [ 368MiB/s] [ <=> ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:04 [ 393MiB/s] [ 393MiB/s] [============>] 100%            
     out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:04 [ 393MiB/s] [ 393MiB/s] [ <=>   ]
3874110+1 records in
3874110+1 records out
     out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:04 [ 393MiB/s] [ 393MiB/s] [ <=>  ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C dd conv=lcase; )  # BSD-dd


1.92s user 4.24s system 127% cpu 4.817 total
85759a34df874966d096c6529dbfb9d5  stdin
```

————————————————————————————————————————

`mawk2` can be made artificially faster than `perl5` by having the file load all at once, and doing `tolower()` for all `1.85 GB` in a single function call ::

```
( time ( pvE0 < "${m3t}" | 

  LC_ALL=C mawk2 '
           BEGIN {            FS = RS = "^$"  } 
             END { print tolower($(ORS = "")) }' 

 ) | pvE9 ) | xxh128sum| lgp3 

      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:00 [3.35GiB/s] [3.35GiB/s] [============>] 100%            
     out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:02 [ 647MiB/s] [ 647MiB/s] [ <=> ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | LC_ALL=C mawk2 ; )


1.39s user 1.31s system 91% cpu 2.935 total
85759a34df874966d096c6529dbfb9d5  stdin
```

Answer (score 3):

For Bash versions earlier than 4.0, this version should be fastest (as it doesn't [fork/exec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec) any commands):

```
function string.monolithic.tolower
{
   local __word=$1
   local __len=${#__word}
   local __char
   local __octal
   local __decimal
   local __result

   for (( i=0; i<__len; i++ ))
   do
      __char=${__word:$i:1}
      case "$__char" in
         [A-Z] )
            printf -v __decimal '%d' "'$__char"
            printf -v __octal '%03o' $(( $__decimal ^ 0x20 ))
            printf -v __char \\$__octal
            ;;
      esac
      __result+="$__char"
   done
   REPLY="$__result"
}
```

[technosaurus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting/8952274#8952274) had potential too, although it did run properly for mee.

Comment: Not bad!  For an analysis of the performance of this approach, please see my answer for metrics.

Answer (score 3):

In spite of how old this question is and similar to [this answer by technosaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8952274/1354571). I had a hard time finding a solution that was portable across most platforms (That I Use) as well as older versions of bash. I have also been frustrated with arrays, functions and use of prints, echos and temporary files to retrieve trivial variables. This works very well for me so far I thought I would share.
My main testing environments are:

> 1. GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
> 2. GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)

```
lcs="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
ucs="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
input="Change Me To All Capitals"
for (( i=0; i<"${#input}"; i++ )) ; do :
    for (( j=0; j<"${#lcs}"; j++ )) ; do :
        if [[ "${input:$i:1}" == "${lcs:$j:1}" ]] ; then
            input="${input/${input:$i:1}/${ucs:$j:1}}" 
        fi
    done
done
```

Simple [C-style for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552175/1354571) to iterate through the strings.
For the line below if you have not seen anything like this before
[this is where I learned this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html). In this case the line checks if the char ${input:$i:1} (lower case) exists in input and if so replaces it with the given char ${ucs:$j:1} (upper case) and stores it back into input.

```
input="${input/${input:$i:1}/${ucs:$j:1}}"
```

Comment: This is wildly inefficient, looping 650 times in your example above, and taking 35 seconds to execute 1000 invocations on my machine.  For an alternative that loops just 11 times and takes less than 5 seconds to execute 1000 invocations, see my alternative answer.

Comment: Thanks, although that should be obvious just from looking at it. Perhaps the page faults are from the input size and the number of iterations you are executing. Nevertheless I like your solution.

Answer (score 3):

To store the transformed string into a variable. Following worked for me -
`$SOURCE_NAME` to `$TARGET_NAME`

```
TARGET_NAME="`echo $SOURCE_NAME | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Dejay Clayton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573758/14179001) excellent solution, I've generalized the uppercase/lowercase to a transpose function (independently useful), returned the result in a variable (faster/safer), and added a BASH v4+ optimization:

```sh
pkg::transpose() { # <retvar> <string> <from> <to>
  local __r=$2 __m __p
  while [[ ${__r} =~ ([$3]) ]]; do
    __m="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; __p="${3%${__m}*}"
    __r="${__r//${__m}/${4:${#__p}:1}}"
  done
  printf -v "$1" "%s" "${__r}"
}
pkg::lowercase() { # <retvar> <string>
  if (( BASH_VERSINFO[0] >= 4 )); then
    printf -v "$1" "%s" "${2,,}"
  else
    pkg::transpose "$1" "$2" "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" \
                   "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  fi
}
pkg::uppercase() { # <retvar> <string>
  if (( BASH_VERSINFO[0] >= 4 )); then
    printf -v "$1" "%s" "${2^^}"
  else
    pkg::transpose "$1" "$2" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" \
                   "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  fi
}
```

To keep things simple I didn't add any set -e support (or any error checking really)... but otherwise it generally follows [shellguide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html) and `pkg::transpose()` tries to avoid any likely variable name clashes for the `printf -v`

Answer (score 0):

isn't this cleaner than a full chain of  `shell variable(s)` + `declare` + `eval` + `single quote escapes` + `echo` + `pipe(s)` + `tr` just to avoid a sub-shell or external process ?

> ```
> # ***MUCH*** faster for ASCII only
>
> mawk '$!NF = toupper($_)' <<< 'abcxyz'
> ```

```
ABCXYZ
```

> ```
> gawk '$_ = tolower($_)' <<< 'FAB-EDC'
> ```

```
fab-edc
```

and Unicodes are just as easy to work with, without having to "unpack" or "encode" or "decode" bytes

> ```
> printf '%s' "${test_utf8}" | ……
> ```

```
 1  ÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øù
    úûüýþÿĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪī
    ĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝ
    ŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžſƀƁƂƃƄƅƆƇƈƉƊƋƌƍƎƏ
    ƐƑƒƓƔƕƖƗƘƙƚƛƜƝƞƟƠơƢƣƤƥƦƧƨƩƪƫƬƭƮƯưƱƲƳƴƵƶƷƸƹƺƻƼƽƾƿǀǁǂ
    ǃǄǅǆǇǈǉǊǋǌǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǝǞǟǠǡǢǣǤǥǦǧǨǩǪǫǬǭǮǯǰǱǲǳǴ
```

> ```
> …… | gawk '$_ = toupper($_)'
> ```

```
 1  ÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ÷ØÙ
    ÚÛÜÝÞŸĀĀĂĂĄĄĆĆĈĈĊĊČČĎĎĐĐĒĒĔĔĖĖĘĘĚĚĜĜĞĞĠĠĢĢĤĤĦĦĨĨĪĪ
    ĬĬĮĮİIĲĲĴĴĶĶĸĹĹĻĻĽĽĿĿŁŁŃŃŅŅŇŇŉŊŊŌŌŎŎŐŐŒŒŔŔŖŖŘŘŚŚŜŜ
    ŞŞŠŠŢŢŤŤŦŦŨŨŪŪŬŬŮŮŰŰŲŲŴŴŶŶŸŹŹŻŻŽŽSƀƁƂƂƄƄƆƇƇƉƊƋƋƍƎƏ
    ƐƑƑƓƔǶƖƗƘƘƚƛƜƝȠƟƠƠƢƢƤƤƦƧƧƩƪƫƬƬƮƯƯƱƲƳƳƵƵƷƸƸƺƻƼƼƾǷǀǁǂ
    ǃǄǅǄǇǈǇǊǋǊǍǍǏǏǑǑǓǓǕǕǗǗǙǙǛǛƎǞǞǠǠǢǢǤǤǦǦǨǨǪǪǬǬǮǮǰǱǲǱǴ
```

Answer (score -16):

use this command to do the same , it will convert upper case strings into lowercase :

```
sed 's/[A-Z]/[a-z]/g' <filename>
```

Comment: That doesn't work at all. It replaces each upper case letter by the 5-character string `[a-z]`!