# Not getting output of Following Shell script

Tags: linux, cygwin

Thanks For your Valuable support, Now i m able to run shell script in cygwin using java.

But I am facing some problem with following method.

```
ConvertToUpperCase()
{
  rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' *
  cd APPBUILD
  rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' *
  cd DISKS
  rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' *
  cd SEATAPP
  rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' *
  cd ../../../
}
```

This Function is not executing in cygwin. Can any one suggest how to Debug shell script in Cygwin. Or Do i Need to change Function for the same.

**Edit Note:** Removed Java Tag..

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Comment: Sorry I removed Java Tag

Comment: How did you call this function? What is the output when you run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
up(){
  for i in *; do
    mv "$i" "${i^^}"
  done
}

ConvertToUpperCase(){
  up
  cd APPBUILD
  up
  cd DISKS
  up
  cd SEATAPP
  up
  cd ../../../
}
```

## [stackoverflow.com/a/2265268](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265268)