# character case conversion Uppercase to Lower and vice versa

Tags: shell, unix

I was trying to convert the lowercase characters to uppercase. I came across various alternatives like one listing at the StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting). However, What i saw that these are just printed. I want to save it to another variable which i can use later.
Can anyone tell how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your input is `$a`. The new variable is `$b`.
(borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2264537/938111) written by @ghostdog74)

using **`tr`**:

```
b=$( tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< $a)
```

if you use `tcsh`, then use `echo` instead of `<<<`:

```
set b=`echo "$a" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
```

Comment: You should post these as separated answers :)

Comment: Is that for tcsh? Consider the following as you mentioned gives error.  
<pre><code>
#! /bin/tcsh  
set a = "Helo World!"  
echo $a '<-'
set b = $(tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< $a )  # error
echo 'a=' $a 'b=' $b  
</code>
</pre>  
The shell gives me error : "Illegal variable name." at line 4

Comment: Hey @abhinav. I have fixed the `tcsh` version. I am sorry for the late, not so familiar with `tcsh`. Have fun ;-)

Comment: yea, having multiple separate answers (especially 1-liners) is discouraged. Best to have them all in one answer

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an oldish post but I made this answer for another site so I thought I'd post it up here:

here comes a programmers answer....

**UPPER -> lower**:
use python:

```
b=`echo "print '$a'.lower()" | python`
```

Or Ruby:

```
b=`echo "print '$a'.downcase" | ruby`
```

Or Perl (probably my favorite):

```
b=`perl -e "print lc('$a');"`
```

Or PHP:

```
b=`php -r "print strtolower('$a');"`
```

Or Awk:

```
b=`echo "$a" | awk '{ print tolower($1) }'`
```

Or Sed:

```
b=`echo "$a" | sed 's/./\L&/g'`
```

Or Bash 4:

```
b=${a,,}
```

Or NodeJS if you have it:

```
b=`echo "console.log('$a'.toLowerCase());" | node`
```

You could also use `dd` (but I wouldn't!):

```
b=`echo "$a" | dd  conv=lcase 2> /dev/null`
```

**lower -> UPPER**:

use python:

```
b=`echo "print '$a'.upeer()" | python`
```

Or Ruby:

```
b=`echo "print '$a'.upcase" | ruby`
```

Or Perl (probably my favorite):

```
b=`perl -e "print uc('$a');"`
```

Or PHP:

```
b=`php -r "print strtoupper('$a');"`
```

Or Awk:

```
b=`echo "$a" | awk '{ print toupper($1) }'`
```

Or Sed:

```
b=`echo "$a" | sed 's/./\U&/g'`
```

Or Bash 4:

```
b=${a^^}
```

Or NodeJS if you have it:

```
b=`echo "console.log('$a'.toUpperCase());" | node`
```

You could also use `dd` (but I wouldn't!):

```
b=`echo "$a" | dd  conv=ucase 2> /dev/null`
```

Also when you say 'shell' I'm assuming you mean `bash` but if you can use `zsh` it's as easy as

```
b=$a:l
```

for lower case and

```
b=$a:u
```

for upper case.

Comment: how about capitalize the first letter on `zsh`, do you have any reference for these commands? @nettux

Comment: @mochadwi You'd use `b=${(C)a}`. See the parameter expansion section from the zsh docs here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags

Answer (score 4):

using  **`bash` 4.0**:

```
b=${a,,}
```

Comment: this just awesome.

Answer (score 2):

using **`awk`**:

```
b=$( awk '{print tolower($0)}' <<< $a )
```

Answer (score 2):

using **`perl`**:

```
b=$( perl -e 'print lc <>;' <<< $a )
```

Answer (score 0):

All the previous answers are correct, I'm just adding this because there is no need to declare variable etc if you are simply converting texts.

```
echo changethistoupper | tr [a-z] [A-Z]
echo CHANGETHISTOLOWER | tr [A-Z] [a-z]
```

[image]