# How can I convert uppercase to lowercase or the other way around in Bash?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [converting string to lower case in bash shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting)

For example:

```
 echo *****Language translator*****
 echo please choose the language
 for Chinese enter c
 for French enter f
```

In a simple way I want to be able to recognize both C and c for Chinese;
and the same thing for f and F, recognized as French.

Is there a way to convert everything to lower case?

Here part of the code:

if [ $language == c ];
      then
        echo "Enter the word to translate:"
        read word_to_translate

Comment: This question actually has a lot more examples that might fit your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting

Comment: There's probably a better way to do this overall. How are you detecting a selection?

Comment: Please provide me an example using my example. Thanks

Comment: I'm adding more content since this does not seems to be clear.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `tr` to switch the chars to lowercase/uppercase:

```
echo $language | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'
```

Comment: what if they mispelled chinese or french?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following case-modifiers (from `man bash`):

```
${parameter^}      # Convert the first character in ${parameter} to uppercase
${parameter^^}     # Convert all characters in ${parameter} to uppercase
${parameter,}      # Convert the first character in ${parameter} to lowercase
${parameter,,}     # Convert all characters in ${parameter} to lowercase
```

So your code might look something like this:

```
# Read one character into $lang, with a nice prompt.
read -n 1 -p "Please enter c for Chinese, or f for French: " lang
if [ "${lang,,}" == "c" ]; then
  echo "Chinese"
elif [ "${lang,,}" == "f" ]; then
  echo "French"
else
  echo "I don't speak that language."
fi
```

Comment: sorry but what does -n 1 -p means?

Comment: @cacosud: `-n 1` means just read one character without waiting for the user to press return, and `-p` means use the following as a prompt (a rather cleaner way of doing it than `echo`).

Comment: Sorry for being unclear; thanks for the explanation, @GordonDavisson.  I've added a comment to help.

Answer (score 2):

Modern versions of tr have support for POSIX character classes  [:upper:]  and [:lower:]

```
tr -s '[:upper:]'  '[:lower:]' < inputfile > outputfile
```

All of the character classes are here:

```
http://ss64.com/bash/tr.html
```

Comment: **Be careful with that '-s'** -- it means "squeeze repeated chars into one" -- so, if you do `echo "FOOZBALL" | tr -s '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` you'll end up with "fozbal".  Which may not be what you wanted.  (For some reason, this variation of the answer is all over the Internets.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use a case statement, though there are other ways to do it:

```
read language
case "$language" in
([cC]) echo 'Chinese';;
([fF]) echo 'French';;
(*)    echo 'Unrecognized language abbreviation';;
esac
```

You could make a canonical assignment in the `case` if you need the values outside the switch:

```
read language
case "$language" in
([cC]) lingua='zh_tw'; echo 'Chinese';;
([fF]) lingua='fr_fr'; echo 'French';;
(*)    echo 'Unrecognized language abbreviation';;
esac
```

Comment: I'd always seen a case written as, e.g., `c|C) echo 'Chinese';;`  Learn something new on SO every day!

Comment: @AdamLiss: that also works.  The 'real' Bourne shell doesn't like the open parenthesis before the expression; the POSIX shell (and hence `bash` and `ksh`) allows, but does not require, the leading parenthesis, and I use it because it makes it easier to 'match parentheses' in `vim`.  The square brackets are part of the shell globbing, of course.

Comment: How can I use this in a if statement? for example

Comment: You can't - or don't.  The `case` is analogous to a multi-way `if` statement in its own right.

Comment: Re-re-reading the man page, I see that bash has also evolved to support "falling through" from one case to the next, optionally requiring the next pattern to match before executing the corresponding commands.

Comment: In other words, `case $a in B) echo foo; lang=x-foo;; esac` is analogous to `if [ "$a" = "B" ] ; then echo foo; lang=x-foo; fi`