# String Boolean in Bash

Tags: string, bash, boolean

I'm trying to create a script that takes two parameters: a word and a character, then returns how many times the character appears in the word.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
((counter=0))
for i in $1
do
if i == $2   
then
((counter=counter+1))
fi

echo $counter
done
```

My script returns 1 every time. I'm only versed in python, so my bash syntax is poor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How it's been done before http://stackoverflow.com/a/10552175/529630

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try the following simple bash code

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0; i<${#1}; i++)); do
    [[ $2 == ${1:$i:1} ]] && ((count++))
done

echo "There's $count occurrences of $2 in $1"
```

Comment: can you explain what exactly ${1:$i:1} does?

Comment: It's a bash _parameter expansion_ : you specify the offset to print an arbitrary length of the string. Search _Substring expansion_ :  http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: It's a substring command. It looks confusing as the first arg is the name of the variable (`1`, as in `$1`), the second is the start index, and third is the length to take.

Comment: `${v:2:3}` extracts a substring of `$v` at index 2 of length 3.

Comment: I'm receiving this error: 

    ./countchars: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./countchars: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file, nevermind, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you use Bash syntax,

```
grep -c "$2" <<<"$1"
```

For POSIX shell, you need to `echo` or (preferably) `printf` the string and pipe to `grep`.

The shell does not decompose a token into individual characters when you loop over it (and, some argue, neither should Python actually :-) -- `for i in foo` simply sets `i` to `foo`.