# bash loop through all chars in string

Tags: bash, shell

How should I loop through all chars in a string.

My pseudocode

```
stringVar="abcde"

for var in stringvar
{
   do some things with var
}
```

result i need
a

b

c

d

I want to loop all the vars but i can only get it to work with a whitespace splitted var like

```
 stringVar="a b c"


for var in stringVar; do
   echo $var
done;
```

result

a

b

c

but i cant do it for a string that isnt split with whitespaces.

**The question is flagged as duplicate but not one of the answers (with upvotes) is available in the linked questions..**

Comment: @alfasin they dont explain how to perform an action on each char.

Comment: [Yes they do](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10552175/635608), @SvenB

Comment: Why is this something that you believe you need to do?

Comment: read this answer more carefully. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551981/how-to-perform-a-for-loop-on-each-character-in-a-string-in-bash/10552078#10552078

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i try to loop trough a word and check for each var if it is in another word, if one is not i must return false else if all are in the other word return true;

Comment: Then why wouldn't you just ask about that in the first place?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I tought it would be to specific and i could do it myself if i could loop all the vars,

Comment: @Mat the solutions are also different, i think the solutions on my question are better.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ive posted another question thats more specific

Comment: @SvenB [What you believe...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594032/bash-shell-test-if-all-var-in-one-string-are-in-another-string

Answer (score 7):

You can use `read` for that:

```
string="abcde"
while read -n 1 char ; do
    echo "$char"
done <<< "$string"
```

Using `-n 1` `read` will read one character at a time. However, the input redirection `<<<` adds a newline to the end of `$string`.

Comment: this method skips white spaces, unfortunately

Comment: can't reproduce

Comment: you used `echo` which creates a new line on each iteration. if you try with `printf` you'll see that this method skips spaces. here is an [example](https://repl.it/@almaceleste/loop-chars#main.sh)

Comment: ok, you have to use `IFS= read -n 1 char` to read spaces too. example: [read-spaces](https://repl.it/@almaceleste/read-spaces#main.sh)

Comment: @almaceleste https://pastebin.com/BTZ7BNjB

Comment: @hek2ml, your example does not work with spaces - it skips them. to test this behavior simply change `echo "@char"` to `printf "@char"` or use `echo` with some mark in the beginning and ending of the printed string, for example `'` (single quote) - like `echo "'$char'"`. [here](https://repl.it/@almaceleste/loop-chars-2#main.sh) is your code with single quotes appended to the `echo` command.  
if you want the command `read -n 1 char` to read spaces, you need to prepend it with `IFS=` or `IFS=""` or `IFS=''` like in this [example](https://repl.it/@almaceleste/loop-chars-3#main.sh)

Comment: ps: will review my answer later, at work atm.. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
stringVar="abcde"
for ((i=1;i<=${#stringVar};i++)); do
  echo ${stringVar:$i-1:1}
done
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Comment: Why not `for ((i = 0; i < ${#stringVar}; i++)); do  echo ${stringVar:$i:1}` ?