# How to iterate through each letter in a string in Unix Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to iterate through a string taken as an input through the **read** command. I'm trying to output the number of each letter and each letter It should then use a loop to output each letter in turn. For example, if the user enters "picasso", the output should be:

Letter 1: p
Letter 2: i
Letter 3: c
Letter 4: a
Letter 5: s
Letter 6: s
Letter 7: o

Here is my current code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prompt a user to enter a word and output each letter in turn.


read -p "Please enter a word: " word

for i in $word
do
 echo "Letter $i: $word"
done
```

Should I be placing the input to an array? I'm still new to programming loops but I'm finding it impossible to figure out the logic.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551981/how-to-perform-a-for-loop-on-each-character-in-a-string-in-bash)

Answer (score 19):

Combining answers from dtmilano and patrat would give you:

```
read -p "Please enter a word: " word

for i in $(seq 1 ${#word})
do
 echo "Letter $i: ${word:i-1:1}"
done
```

${#word} gives you the length of the string.

Answer (score 6):

Use the substring operator

```
 ${word:i:1}
```

to obtain the i'th character of word.

Answer (score 2):

Check out seq mechanism in bash

For example:

```
seq 1 10
```

Will give you

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

You can try with letters

```
echo {a..g}
```

Result

```
 a b c d e f g
```

Now you should handle your problem

Comment: How would you use this approach to loop through a generic string like "Hello"?

Comment: @oliv presented solution about I was thinking