# Bash: How to extract digits from a number

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So I introduce a number to my script, just like this:

```
./script 795
```

and I'd like to extract each digit from that number and check if it's smaller than 7. Something like:

```
if [ 7 -le 7 ]
then 
echo "The first digit is smaller than 7"
```

I'd like to know how to extract each digit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform a for loop on each character in a string in BASH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551981/how-to-perform-a-for-loop-on-each-character-in-a-string-in-bash)

Comment: Your question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10551981/2988730. The input variable is argument 1: `$1` inside the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a substring to extract the first character of the first argument to your script:

```
if [ ${1:0:1} -lt 7 ]; then
    echo "The first digit is smaller than 7"
fi
```

To do this for each character, then you can use a loop:

```
for (( i = 0; i < ${#1}; ++i )); do
    if [ ${1:$i:1} -lt 7 ]; then
        echo "Character $i is smaller than 7"
    fi
done
```

Notes that I've changed `-le` (less than or equal) to `-lt` (less than) to make your message correct.