# How to iterate over the characters of a string in a POSIX shell script?

Tags: shell, sh, posix, dash-shell

A POSIX compliant shell shall provide mechanisms like this to iterate over collections of strings:

```
for x in $(seq 1 5); do
    echo $x
done
```

But, how do I iterate over each character of a word?

Comment: (As an aside, `seq` isn't POSIX-specified; one mechanism for counting to 5 POSIX-ly might be `i=0; while [ "$i" -lt 5 ]; do echo "$i"; i=$((i + 1)); done`)

Comment: I was trying to demonstrate how to perform an iteration. The `seq` command is not part of the mechanism that performs the iteration. But you are right about your example being POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a little circuitous, but I think this'll work in any posix-compliant shell. I've tried it in `dash`, but I don't have busybox handy to test with.

```
var='ab * cd'

tmp="$var"    # The loop will consume the variable, so make a temp copy first
while [ -n "$tmp" ]; do
    rest="${tmp#?}"    # All but the first character of the string
    first="${tmp%"$rest"}"    # Remove $rest, and you're left with the first character
    echo "$first"
    tmp="$rest"
done
```

Output:

```
a
b

*

c
d
```

Note that the double-quotes around the right-hand side of assignments are not needed; I just prefer to use double-quotes around all expansions rather than trying to keep track of where it's safe to leave them off. On the other hand, the double-quotes in `[ -n "$tmp" ]` are absolutely necessary, and the inner double-quotes in `first="${tmp%"$rest"}"` are needed if the string contains "*".

Comment: Seems to choke on multibyte characters in busybox sh and dash, but not in bash or ksh.

Comment: `LC_CTYPE=C` to the rescue?

Comment: dash under Ubuntu seems to process the string byte-by-byte (rather than character-by-character) no matter what `LC_CTYPE` is set to; I'm guessing that ash under busybox does the same. If you need proper character-by-character processing, this'll make things more complicated.

Comment: I think that for ASCII characters it will be fine. For unicode, I don't think so.

Comment: @LuisLavaire Do you need proper Unicode support for your application? If so, I don't think there's an easy way to build it in a shell that doesn't do Unicode itself; it'd depend on using some utility that's available and properly supports Unicode across every platform you need it to work on.

Comment: No, @GordonDavisson. I just need to manipulate ASCII characters, mostly letters, so your example will work. Thanks.

Comment: `first="${tmp%"$rest"}"` looks slow. alternative: `first="$(echo "$tmp" | head -c1)"`

Comment: @milahu That alternative will actually be a lot slower, because it needs to create new subprocesses to run the `echo` and `head` programs, and creating processes is computationally expensive. `first="${tmp%"$rest"}"` does everything in the shell process, so it actually winds up much faster. Try them and see for yourself!

Answer (score 3):

Use [getopts](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) to process input one character at a time. The `:` instructs getopts to ignore illegal options and set OPTARG. The leading `-` in the input makes getopts treat the string as a options.

If getopts encounters a colon, it will not set `OPTARG`, so the script uses parameter expansion to return `:` when `OPTARG` is not set/null.

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS='
'
split_string () {
  OPTIND=1;
  while getopts ":" opt "-$1"
    do echo "'${OPTARG:-:}'"
  done
}

while read -r line;do
  split_string "$line"
done
```

As with the accepted answer, this processes strings byte-wise instead of character-wise, corrupting multibyte codepoints. The trick is to detect multibyte codepoints, concatenate their bytes and then print them:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS='
'
split_string () {
  OPTIND=1;
  while getopts ":" opt "$1";do
    case "${OPTARG:=:}" in
      ([[:print:]])
        [ -n "$multi" ] && echo "$multi" && multi=
        echo "$OPTARG" && continue
    esac
    multi="$multi$OPTARG"
    case "$multi" in
      ([[:print:]]) echo "$multi" && multi=
    esac
  done
  [ -n "$multi" ] && echo "$multi"
}
while read -r line;do
  split_string "-$line"
done
```

Here the extra `case "$multi"` is used to detect when the multi buffer contains a printable character. This works on shells like Bash and Zsh but Dash and busybox ash do not pattern match multibyte codepoints, ignoring [locale](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html).

This degrades somewhat nicely: Dash/ash treat sequences of multibyte codepoints as one character, but handle multibyte characters surrounded by single byte characters fine.

Depending on your requirements it may be preferable not to split consecutive multibyte codepoints anyway, as the next codepoint may be a [combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) which modifies the character *before* it.

This won't handle the case where a single byte character is followed by a combining character.

Comment: Interesting. It may improve performance problems with large strings. I don't know if it will work, but I've tried to improve on your idea. `split_string() { OPTIND=1; while getopts ":" opt "-$1"; do echo "'$OPTARG'"; done; }`

Comment: @KoichiNakashima very nice! On my laptop it's 1.4x faster at parsing 312Kb text file, and 55x faster than using `sed`

Answer (score 2):

This works in `dash` and `busybox`:

```
echo 'ab * cd' | grep -o .
```

Output:

```
a
b

*

c
d
```

Comment: As @Gordon Davisson mentioned, the `-o` option for `grep` isn't POSIX-compatible.

Comment: @LuisLavaire, Thanks.  I'll leave it up for now, since it does work with *busybox* `grep`...

Answer (score -1):

I was developing a script which demanded stacks... So, we can use it to iterate through strings

```
#!/bin/sh
# posix script

pop () {
#    $1 top
#    $2 stack
    eval $1='$(expr "'\$$2'" : "\(.\).*")'
    eval $2='$(expr "'\$$2'" : ".\(.*\)" )'
}

string="ABCDEFG"
while [ "$string" != "" ]
do
    pop c string
    echo "--" $c
done
```