# Insert formatted text into VIM for every letter of alphabet

Tags: bash, vim

In VIM, for every *letter* of the English alphabet, I want to insert a line in the following format:

`fragment {upper(letter)}: '{lower(letter)}' | '{upper(letter)'};`

So, for example, for the letter **a**, it would be:

`fragment A: 'a' | 'A';`

Writing 26 lines like this is tedious, and [you shouldn't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vim:

```
for i in range(65,90) " ASCII codes
  let c = nr2char(i)  " Character
  echo "fragment" c ": '"tolower(c)"' | '" c "';"
endfor
```

Or as a oneliner:

```
:for i in range(65,90) | let c = nr2char(i) | echo "fragment" c ": '"tolower(c)"' | '" c "';" | endfor
fragment A : ' a ' | ' A ';
fragment B : ' b ' | ' B ';
fragment C : ' c ' | ' C ';
...
fragment X : ' x ' | ' X ';
fragment Y : ' y ' | ' Y ';
fragment Z : ' z ' | ' Z ';
```

Use `:redir @a` to copy that output to register `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.

First, I'm gonna create the text in `bash` with a single command, then I'll tell VIM to insert the *output* of that command into the file.

I need to iterate through English alphabets, and for every letter, `echo` one line in the specified format. So at first, let's just echo each letter in a single line ([By using a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552175/6282576)):

```
❯ alphabets="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
❯ for ((i=0; i<${#alphabets}; i++)); do echo "${alphabets:$i:1}"; done
a
b
...
z
```

The way this works is:

- `${#alphabets}` is equal to the *length* of the variable `alphabets`.
- `${alphabets:$i:1}` [extracts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428580/6282576) the letter at position `i` from the variable `alphabets` (zero-based).

Now we need to convert these letters to *upper case*. Here's [one way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344791/223320) we can achieve this:

```
❯ echo "a" | tr a-z A-Z
A
```

Now if we apply this to the for loop we had, we get this:

```
❯ for ((i=0; i<${#alphabets}; i++)); do echo "${alphabets:$i:1}" | tr a-z A-Z; done 
A
B
...
Z
```

From here, it's quite easy to produce the text we wanted:

```
❯ for ((i=0; i<${#alphabets}; i++)); do c="${alphabets:$i:1}"; cap=$(echo "${c}" | tr a-z A-Z); echo "fragment ${cap}: '${c}' | '${cap}';"; done 
fragment A: 'a' | 'A';
fragment B: 'b' | 'B';
...
fragment Z: 'z' | 'Z';
```

Now that we generated the text, we can simply use `:r !command` to insert the text into vim:

```
:r !alphabets="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; for ((i=0; i<${\#alphabets}; i++)); do c="${alphabets:$i:1}"; cap=$(echo "${c}" | tr a-z A-Z); echo "fragment ${cap}: '${c}' | '${cap}';"; done
```

Note that `#` is a special character in vim and should be spaced using `\`.

Here's another one-liner that does the same thing, and I believe is more intuitive:

```
for c in {a..z}; do u=$(echo ${c} | tr a-z A-Z); echo "fragment ${u}: '${c}' | '${u}';"; done
```

Comment: I like that solution. Here's a counter +1.