# bash script lowercase every string in the input file and output result to new file

Tags: linux, bash

how to lowercase everything in a text file and then output the result to a new file in bash script? for example the input file contains

```
a
bC
D
E
```

output

```
a
bc
d
e
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tr` command:

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < infile > outfile
```

Comment: Better: `'[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`