# How to capitalize all files in the current directory using terminal?

Tags: macos, svn, command-line, terminal

I am trying to capitalize all files in my current working directory using the following command:

```
ls | awk '{system("svn mv " $0 " " toupper(substr($0,1,1)) substr($0,2))}'
```

Yet, I am getting the following error message:

```
svn: '.' is not a working copy
svn: '.' is not a working copy
svn: '.' is not a working copy
svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

I am on a osx. Could you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried doing one of those `svn` commands manually to see whether it works? Does `svn info` work in that directory?

Answer (score 0):

you should not use ls in scripting, ls is for human presentation of data (and will surprise your scripts with space in names, special folders like . and .. like here and so on...), try instead:

```
for f in *;do;svn mv $f $(echo $f| tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]');done
```

[See here for other case conversions alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting), I used tr since awk is not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the directory containing the files you want to capitalize using the cd command. For example:

```
cd path/to/directory
```

Run the following command to capitalize all file names in the current directory:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< "${f:0:1}")${f:1}"; done
```

This command uses a loop to iterate over each file (*) in the directory and renames it using the mv command. The ${f:0:1} extracts the first character of each file name (which is then converted to uppercase using tr), and ${f:1} extracts the rest of the file name. The result is a capitalized file name.

After running this command, all files in the current directory should have their names capitalized.