# unix formatting output variables

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am writing a program that will take fields of data to create usernames and passwords

Here is how the data is formatted

```
MWS1990 XXX-XX-XXXX STASNY, MATTHEW W SO-II BISS CPSC BS   INFO TECH   412/882-0581
```

here is the program

```
for linePosition in {11..22}
do
  holder=`sed -n "${linePosition}p" $1|awk '{print $1}'`
  holder2=`sed -n "${linePosition}p" $1|awk '{print $12}'`
  holder3=`sed -n "${linePosition}p" $1|awk '{print $7}'`
  echo "UserName"
  echo "$holder"
  echo "password"
  echo "$holder2"
  echo "$holder3"
done
```

It returns an output like this

```
UserName
MWS1990
password
412/882-0581
BISS
```

The thing 2 things that are wrong are

1. I would like it to remove the year after username. So the above
   example would instead be just MWS. What can I add to **holder=`sed -n
   "${linePosition}p" $1|awk '{print $1}'** to make it return just the
   first 3 letters. (preferably in lower case but not necessary)
2. I would like to remove the first 6 letters of the phone number. So instead of **412/882-0581**
   the phone number would read **0581**

Comment: The page you need to reference http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html I will write up an answer to explain how to extract the strings as you need them shortly.

Comment: @rob-kielty: Sorry, didn't mean to hijack your answer! Looks like I hit "Post" some seconds after you added this comment.

Comment: LOL That's ok. There's more than one way to skin a string. :-D I up voted your answer and Olaf's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is a revised answer

```
for linePosition in {11..22}
do
  holder=`sed -n "${linePosition}p" $1|awk '{print $1}'`
  holder2=`sed -n "${linePosition}p" $1|awk '{print $12}'`
  holder3=`sed -n "${linePosition}p" $1|awk '{print $7}'`
  echo "UserName"
  echo `expr match "$holder" '\([A-Z|a-z]*\)'`
  echo "password"
  echo ${holder2: -4}
  echo "$holder3"
done
```

Now I am sticking with the bash string substitution as described in the link I posted in the comment.

However I would like to point out the following caveat about this solution

Here's a quick description of the following line of bash scripting ...

```
`expr match "$holder" '\([A-Z|a-z]*\)'`
```

The backticks execute a **subshell** within your for loop  and they run the `expr` command passing in  `match` which returns that part of the string `$holder` which matches the regular expression `[A-Z|a-z]*` at the start of the string. Ref http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Now if your data file is not too long then this will be OK.

However, if your script has to process a **large data file** then I would suggest that you look at Olaf's solution.

Why?

If you are processing a massive file or if you do not know the size of the file that is to be processed by your script that it is best to avoid executing sub-shells *within for loops*.

Olaf's solution where he exploits **awk** to carry out the processing that you require has a important advantage in that all the work takes place *within a single process*. Whereas the for loop that forks and execs a new instance of bash *for each line of your file.* An expensive operation which can be risky one when placed in a for loop.

For your code we can see that currently the for loop is bound by a small set of lines but if this is ever changed or a bug was introduced into the for loop whereby it ran forever then the script could adversely affect the performance of your machine.

So although my answer may have been easier to adapt to your code. Olaf's answer is better if you have to process a large amount of data.

Comment: THANKS! this works except for user name which returns the 4 numbers. what is the way to make is do the first 3 letters of the user name.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already use [`awk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), you can reduce the involved commands

```
awk 'NR >= 11 && NR <= 22 {
    print "UserName";
    print tolower(substr($1, 1, 3));
    print "password";
    print substr($12, 9);
    print $7;}' $1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bash, you can do both of those things easily with Bash [substring extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428580/825783) (see also [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html#SUBSTREXTR01)).

In other words, something like:

```
echo ${holder2:0:3} # "MWS"
echo ${holder3:8:12} # "0581"

# Or, to begin indexing from the right end:

echo ${holder3:(-4)} # "0581"
```

As for converting a string to lowercase in Bash, see e.g. ghostdog74's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2264537/825783).