# Why am I getting this 'bad substitution' error in my bash command?

Tags: bash

when I run this I get this 'bad substitution' error. What can I do?

```
$ x="Hello World"
$ echo "$x"
Hello World
$ echo "${x^^}"
-bash: ${x^^}: bad substitution
```

EDIT: I would like to have it in all upper case.

Comment: What version of `bash` are you running?

Comment: Works for GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4).

Comment: The case modification operators were added in bash 4.

Comment: I am running this (how can I update?): GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: The Bash that comes with OS X is ancient. [`brew install bash`](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/).

Comment: @Kevin: `zsh: bad substitution` ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting string to lower case in bash shell scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting).

Comment: I don't get this: `bash --version` : 
`GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0)`.  `ICAO="EDDF"; echo "${ICAO,,}"` yields `-bash: ${ICAO,,}: bad substitution`. Anyone knows why?

Comment: @Mojo66 you're sure the bash script uses the same bash executable? Try `which bash` and compare to the shebang in the script.

Answer (score 9):

Your method only works in bash 4. Try this:

```
echo $x | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
```

Comment: or `cap=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< "$x")`