# Shell Parameter Expansion need the explanation

Tags: shell, parameters, expansion

I'm learning `bash manual`.

At page `27/166`, I really can't understand the last Parameter Expansion:

```
${parameter^pattern} 
${parameter^^pattern} 
${parameter,pattern}
${parameter,,pattern}
```

Can someone please tell me what these expansions mean?

Some examples would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To lowercase

```
$ string="A FEW WORDS"
$ echo ${string,}
a FEW WORDS
$ echo ${string,,}
a few words
```

To uppercase

```
$ string="a few words"
$ echo ${string^}
A few words
$ echo ${string^^}
A FEW WORDS
```

[Converting string to lower case in Bash shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shel)