# Troubleshooting bash script to capitalize first letter in every word

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file in the following format:

```
jAY
JAY
JaY

eVAns
Evans
Evans
```

What I'm trying to do is convert everything to lowercase and then capitalize the first letter of every word. For my script, however, I'm not printing out the correct information.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=names.txt

echo "#################################"
k=1
while read line;do

VAR=$line
VARCAP=$( echo "${VAR}" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')";
VARCAP1=$( echo "${VARCAP}" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sub(/./,toupper(substr($i,1,1)),$i)}1')

echo "Line # $k: $VARCAP1"
((k++))
done < $FILE
echo "Total number of lines in file: $k"
```

Everything was working until I added the line to convert all the letters to lowercase - so that is where my problem lies. This is the first bash script I've ever written, so to say I'm green is an understatement.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: To lowercase: `lc=${line,,}` and to uppercase first letter: `ucfirst=${lc^}`. No need to use `tr` or `awk`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string to lower case in Bash shell scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in a comment of the OP, you can use (in Bash≥4) the following:

```
${var,,}
${var^}
```

to respectively have the expansion of `var` in lowercase and `var` in lowercase with first letter capitalize. The good news is that this also works on each field of an array.

*Note.* It is not clear from you question whether you need to apply this on each *word* of a line, or on each *line*. The following addresses the problem of each word of a line. Please refer to Steven Penny's answer to process only each line.

Here you go, in a much better style!

```
#!/bin/bash

file=names.txt
echo "#################################"
k=1
while read -r -a line_ary;do
    lc_ary=( "${line_ary[@],,}" )
    echo "Line # $k: ${lc_ary[@]^}"
    ((++k))
done < "$file"
echo "Total number of lines in file: $k"
```

First we read each line as an array `line_ary` (each field is a word).

The part `lc_ary=( "${line_ary[@],,}" )` converts each field of `line_ary` to all lowercase and stores the resulting array into `lc_ary`.

We now only need to apply `^` to the array `lc_ary` and echo it.

Comment: +1 for showing how to capitalize the initial letters of multiple words via an array; a heads-up for people on ancient Linux distros and wandering OSX users: `,,` and `^` require `bash 4+`

Answer (score 1):

```sh
declare -c rw
mapfile -t rw < names.txt
printf '%s\n' "${rw[@]}"
```

Result

```
Jay
Jay
Jay

Evans
Evans
Evans
```

[Converting string to lower case in Bash shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2264428/#2265268)

Comment: I think the OP needs to deal with several words per line (well, that's what I understood after carefully reading his code and question). **Edit.** Or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf the question is ambiguous

Comment: why not: `declare -c ary; mapfile -t ary < names.txt; echo "${ary[@]}"`?

Comment: +1 for `-c`; a heads-up for people on ancient Linux distros and wandering OSX users: requires `bash 4+`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf updated. `echo` messes up the spacing for some reason.