# lowercase + capitalize + concatenate words of a string in shell (e.g. bash)

Tags: string, shell, lowercase, capitalization, capitalize

How to capitalize+concatenate words of a string?
(first letter uppercase and all other other letters lowercase)

**example:** 
`input  = "jAMeS bOnD"` 
`output = "JamesBond"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String manipulation available in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) version 4:

- `${variable,,}` to lowercase all letters
- `${variable^}` to uppercase first letter of each word
- use `${words[*]^}` instead of `${words[@]^}` to save some script lines

And other improvements from [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375) (see his comments):

- Variable names in lower-case because upper-case ones may conflict with environment variables
- Give meaningful names to variables (e.g. `ARRAY` -> `words`)
- Use `local` to avoid impacting `IFS` outside the function (once is enougth)
- Use `local` for all other *local* variables ( variable can be first declared, and later assigned)
- `ARRAY=( $LOWERCASE )` may expands [globs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) *(filename [wildcards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character#Computing))*

  - temporarily disable *[Pathname Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs)* using `set -f` or `shopt -so noglob`
  - or use `read -ra words <<< "$input"` instead of `words=( $input )`

## Ultimate function:

```
capitalize_remove_spaces()
{
  local words IFS
  read -ra words <<< "${@,,}"
  IFS=''
  echo "${words[*]^}"
}
```

If you want to keep alphanumeric characters only, extends the [IFS built-in variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) just before the `read -ra words` operation:

```
capitalize_remove_punctuation()
{
  local words IFS=$' \t\n-\'.,;!:*?' #Handle hyphenated names and punctuation
  read -ra words <<< "${@,,}"
  IFS=''
  echo "${words[*]^}"
}
```

## Examples:

```
> capitalize_remove_spaces 'jAMeS bOnD'
JamesBond

> capitalize_remove_spaces 'jAMeS bOnD *'
JamesBond*

> capitalize_remove_spaces 'Jean-luc GRAND-PIERRE'
Jean-lucGrand-pierre

> capitalize_remove_punctuation 'Jean-luc GRAND-PIERRE'
JeanLucGrandPierre

> capitalize_remove_punctuation 'Jean-luc GRAND-PIERRE *'
JeanLucGrandPierre
```

Comment: +1; handy stuff; a few suggestions: it's good practice not to use all-uppercase variable names in shell programming, so as to avoid conflicts with environment variables (though I'd hate to see the wonderfully surrealistic `$LOWERCASE` go :). Creating your word arrays with `ARRAY=( $LOWERCASE )` has a pitfall: the string is subject to _pathname expansion_ so the results will be unexpected if the string contains a glob such as `*`. Turning `set -f` (`shopt -so noglob`) on (temporarily) could fix this. Another option is to use `read -a` to create the array (see my answer).

Comment: I suggest using _local_ variables in your shell _functions_, e.g.: `local IFS=''` - this has the added benefit of not having to restore `$IFS` on leaving the function.

Comment: I appreciate your dedication to improving your answer - these functions are elegant. One final suggestion: I suggest making _all_ variables in the functions _local_.  Plus a quibble: while it works to repeat `local` when assigning `$IFS` the 2nd time, I'd only declare the variable once, at the top. E.g., in the 2nd function you could use `local words IFS=$' \t\n-\'.,;!:*?'` (or use `local` to merely _declare_, then _assign_ later), and then simply `IFS=''` later.

Comment: Thank you @mklement0 :-D I have just applied your last advice :-) And I have also shorten the answer ;-) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **`bash 3+` solution** that utilizes `tr` for case conversion (the case conversion operators (`,`, `^`, ...) were introduced in `bash` *4*):

```
input="jAMeS bOnD"

read -ra words <<<"$input" # split input into an array of words
output="" # initialize output variable
for word in "${words[@]}"; do # loop over all words
  # add capitalized 1st letter
  output+="$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"${word:0:1}")"
  # add lowercase version of rest of word
  output+="$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<"${word:1}")"
done
```

Note:

- Concatenation (removal of whitespace between words) happens implicitly by always directly appending to the output variable.
- It's tempting to want to use `words=( $input )` to split the input string into an array of words, but there's a gotcha: the string is subject to *pathname expansion*, so if a word happens to be a valid glob (e.g., `*`), it will be expanded (replaced with matching filenames), which is undesired; using `read -ra` to create the array avoids this problem (`-a` reads into an array, `-r` turns off interpretation of `\` chars. in the input).

Answer (score 1):

From other posts, I came up with this working script:

```
str="jAMeS bOnD"
res=""
split=`echo $str | sed -e 's/ /\n/g'` # Split with space as delimiter
for word in $split; do
    word=${word,,} # Lowercase
    word=${word^} # Uppercase first letter
    res=$res$word # Concatenate result
done

echo $res
```

References:

- [Converting string to lower case in Bash shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting)
- [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)
- [Troubleshooting bash script to capitalize first letter in every word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398905/troubleshooting-bash-script-to-capitalize-first-letter-in-every-word)

Comment: There is no need for the `sed` command and the intermediate `$split` variable: using an unquoted string with `for` performs word splitting also with spaces, not just newlines; thus, you could just say: `for word in $str; do`. Either way, there is a pitfall: unquoted strings used with `for` are subject to _pathname expansion_, so the results will be unexpected if the string contains a glob such as `*`. Turning `set -f` (`shopt -so noglob`) on (temporarily) could fix this. Note that your solution requires bash _4_ or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk it is little verbose but does the job::

```
s="jAMeS bOnD"
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  
   printf toupper(substr($i, 1, 1)) tolower(substr($i,2)); print ""}' <<< "$s"
JamesBond
```

Comment: Fine, but GNU Awk 3.1.7 says `awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: printf: no arguments`. I had to move down `printf` in the same line as `toupper...`. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -e '\n' "!!!!! PERMISSION to WRITE in  /var/log/ DENIED !!!!!"
echo -e '\n'
echo "Do you want to continue?"
echo -e '\n' "Yes or No"
read -p "Please Respond_: " Response #get input from keyboard "yes/no"
#Capitalizing 'yes/no' with # echo $Response | awk '{print toupper($0)}' or echo $Response | tr [a-z] [A-Z] 
answer=$(echo $Response | awk '{print toupper($0)}') 
case $answer in
    NO)
        echo -e '\n' "Quitting..."
        exit 1
        ;;
    YES)
        echo -e '\n' "Proceeding..."
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Make sure to put some explanation for your answer, not just code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @AMACB I added a comment. The above was just an example one could use to format strings.