# Remove all special characters and case from string in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, parsing

I am writing a bash script that needs to parse filenames.

It will need to remove all special characters (including space): **"!?.-_** and change all uppercase letters to lowercase.  Something like this:

```
Some_randoM data1-A
More Data0
```

to:

```
somerandomdata1a
moredata0
```

I have seen lots of questions to do this in many different programming languages, but not in bash.  Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Lowercase example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting

Comment: Remove spaces here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable

Comment: More generally, Bash regular expressions: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
cat yourfile.txt | tr -dc '[:alnum:]\n\r' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

The first `tr` deletes special characters. `d` means delete, `c` means complement (invert the character set).  So, `-dc` means delete all characters except those specified.  The `\n` and `\r` are included to preserve linux or windows style newlines, which I assume you want.

The second one translates uppercase characters to lowercase.

Comment: Just if you (just like me) came here looking for a solution the get rid of characters like \r \n or ^C in a variable var2=`echo $var | tr -d '[:cntrl:]'` is the solution. Thanks to this answer I figured this out.

Answer (score 38):

Pure BASH 4+ solution:

```
$ filename='Some_randoM data1-A'
$ f=${filename//[^[:alnum:]]/}
$ echo "$f"
SomerandoMdata1A
$ echo "${f,,}"
somerandomdata1a
```

A function for this:

```
clean() {
    local a=${1//[^[:alnum:]]/}
    echo "${a,,}"
}
```

Try it:

```
$ clean "More Data0"
moredata0
```

Comment: +1; the `,,` operator (convert entire string to lowercase) requires `bash 4+`.

Answer (score 22):

if you are using mkelement0 and Dan Bliss approach. You can also look into sed + POSIX regular expression.

```
cat yourfile.txt | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g'
```

Sed matches all other characters that are not contained within the brackets except letters and numbers and remove them.

Comment: Nice answer! You saved my life!

Comment: Very nice. This is useful if you want to use regex.

Answer (score 19):

I've used `tr` to remove any characters that are not part of `[:print:]` class

```
cat file.txt | tr -dc '[:print:]'
```

or

```
echo "..." | tr -dc '[:print:]'
```

Additionally you might want to `|` (pipe) the output to `od -c` to confirm the result

```
cat file.txt | tr -dc '[:print:]' | od -c
```

Comment: `od` was useful for me