# How to adapt the next command to be able to change any character

Tags: linux, bash, file

Im trying to rename a whole bulks of files with underscores, hashtags and a bunch of characters that the ftp servers have trouble dealing it.

I have always have resorted to do it with

```
find . -depth -name '* *' \
| while IFS= read -r f ; do
    mv -i "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f"|tr ' ' _)"
done
```

but I have failed to adapt the tr part to make the change, this way too

```
....tr '(' '_')"
```

here I want to change the ( character.

**UPDATE**
As noted by wjandrea, I did not update the definition in the -name parameter of the find comand, it should be

```
find . -depth -name '*(*'
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? At a glance this looks fine.

Comment: It didnt replace the character (,),#,! for an underscore

Comment: Did you update your `find` command as well? Should be `find . -depth -name '*(*'` for left parens for example.

Comment: Top answer on this question explains how to replace all special characters using `tr` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816264/remove-all-special-characters-and-case-from-string-in-bash) - is this what you're after?

Comment: @wjandrea, I miss that part,

Comment: @jared_mamrot Im reading the article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the space character, `!`, `(`, `)` and `#` with an underscore, you could use:

```
find . -depth -name '*[ !()#]*' -exec sh -c '
  for f; do
    mv -i "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f" | tr " !()#" _)"
  done
' sh {} +
```

---

If your `find` supports the `-execdir` action used in combination with the Perl `rename` tool:

```
find . -name '*[ !()#]*' -execdir rename -n 's/[ !()#]/_/g' {} +
```

Remove option `-n` if the output looks as expected.

Comment: thanks for the Perl trick, I have tryed it before but never got it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your command `tr '(' '_'` translates an open parenthesis into an underscore. Nothing more.

From the `tr` man-page:

```
 tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]

 ....  SET2  is extended to length of SET1 by repeating its last character as necessary. ....
```

Hence, you need to specify all the characters to be translated, for instance:

```
tr '()#!' _
```

Comment: This is what I did before, but It did not work out,  I was thinking the ssame that updating the tr part was enough.  It was needed to update the find part too.

Comment: These are unrelated issues. You can loop using `find` over **all** files, which means that you will do a lot of unnecessary `mv`, and you can already preselect the files in need to be changed inside the `find` command. This is more about efficiency than correctness.