# Replace multiple underscores in filename using bash script

Tags: bash, macos, replace

Doing some reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816264/remove-all-special-characters-and-case-from-string-in-bash) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709458/how-to-replace-spaces-in-file-names-using-a-bash-script) I found this solution to replace two underscores in filenames with only one using bash:

```
for file in *; do
  f=${file//__/_}
  echo $f
done;
```

However how do I most easily expand this expression to replace an arbitrary number of underscores with only one?

Comment: If you have extended globbing (enable it using `shopt -s extglob` if it's not already enabled) you could use `f="${f//+(_)/_}"`. E.g. for the file "test_____something__else.txt", `for f in test_*; do f="${f//+(_)/_}"; echo $f; done` returns `test_something_else.txt`.  More details here: https://askubuntu.com/a/889746

Answer (score 4):

Typically, it's going to be faster to just put your original code in a loop than to do anything else.

```
for file in *; do
  f=$file
  while [[ $f = *__* ]]; do
    f=${f//__/_}
  done
  echo "$f"
done
```

Even better, if you're on a modern shell release, you can enable extended globs, which provide regex-like functionality:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in *; do
  f=${file//+(_)/_}
  echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: Great, number 2 really made things easier. Being a sporadic bash user I find it very hard to figure out these things just by searching manuals and descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regex using `sed`

```sh
for file in *; do
  f=$(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/_\+/_/')
  echo "$f"
done;
```

This regex matches one or more underscores (`_\+`) and substitutes them with only one (`_`)

Comment: `echo "$file"`, not `echo $file`; and `echo "$f"`, not `echo $f`. See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: (also, this is going to be a lot slower than using the OP's original code in a loop; starting a pipeline for every file is expensive!)

Comment: Edited my answer to correct the variable usage, and you are absolutely correct about it being slower. I wouldn't use this in any directory with a lot of files

Answer (score 0):

GNU `tr` has `--squeeze-repeats`:

```
$ echo foo_______bar | tr --squeeze-repeats _
foo_bar
```

If you're using BSD `tr` you can use `-s` instead:

```
$ echo foo_______bar | tr -s _
foo_bar
```

Answer (score 0):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure shell code should work with any POSIX-compliant shell, including `bash` and `dash`:

```
for file in *; do
    while :; do
        case $file in
            *__*)   file=${file%%__*}_${file#*__};;
            *)      break;;
        esac
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

- `${file%%__*}` expands to `$file` with the first `__` and all characters after it removed (e.g. `a__b__c` produces `a`).
- `${file#*__}` expands to `$file` with all characters up to and including the first `__` removed (e.g.  `a__b__c` produces `b__c`).
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why `printf '%s\n' "$file"` is used instead of `echo "$file"`.