# Converting CamelCase to lowerCamelCase with POSIX Shell

Tags: bash, shell, posix

I am trying to only change the first letter of a string to lowercase using a Shell script. Ideally a simple way to go from CamelCase to lowerCamelCase.

GOAL:

```
$DIR="SomeString"
# missing step
$echo $DIR
someString
```

I have found some [great resources for doing this to the entire string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting) but not just altering the first letter and leaving the remaining string untouched.

Comment: @jaypalsingh edited, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

If your shell is recent enough, you can use the following parameter expansion:

```
DIR="SomeString"   # Note the missing dollar sign.
echo ${DIR,}
```

Comment: I'm using OSX and it looks like the default Bash is not very recent.  I get errors when I try and of the Bash v4 features:

bash: ${DIR,}: bad substitution

Comment: @Infinite time to look at [macports.org](http://www.macports.org). You can get many good GNU tools in addition to OSX's BSD tools.

Comment: @jm666 Thanks :D I am well aware of MacPorts and Brew.  This is for a build script that needs to run on a variety of platforms and it is outside out main build scripts which use Rake.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution (will work on old bash too)

```
DIR="SomeString"
echo $(echo ${DIR:0:1} | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]")${DIR:1}
```

prints

```
someString
```

for assing to variable

```
DIR2="$(echo ${DIR:0:1} | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]")${DIR:1}"
echo $DIR2
```

prints

```
someString
```

alternative perl

```
DIR3=$(echo SomeString | perl -ple 's/(.)/\l$1/')
DIR3=$(echo SomeString | perl -nle 'print lcfirst')
DIR3=$(echo "$DIR"     | perl -ple 's/.*/lcfirst/e'
```

some terrible solutions;

```
DIR4=$(echo "$DIR" | sed 's/^\(.\).*/\1/' | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]")$(echo "$DIR" | sed 's/^.//')
DIR5=$(echo "$DIR" | cut -c1 | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]')$(echo "$DIR" | cut -c2-)
```

All the above is tested with OSX's `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Preference is to use `tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]]`, but good solution for BASH.

Comment: Just to let the OP know, this works in BASH on the Mac which is version 3.2.

Answer (score 3):

With sed:

```
var="SomeString"
echo $var | sed 's/^./\L&/'
```

`^` means the start of the line
`\L` is the command to make the match in lowercase
`&` is the whole match

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution, sadly I am using POSIX sed so I don't have access to \L.

Comment: Take a look at your `sed` manpage and at your `re_format` manpage. Sometimes if you use `-E` in `sed`, it will use the _expanded regular expressions_ which may or may not include `\L`. You may also see other parameters that can be passed to `sed` that can expand its regular expression ability.

Comment: You actually can do this on mac if you use homebrew: https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
DIR=SomeString
perl -le 'print lcfirst shift' "$DIR"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since awk hasn't yet been mentioned, here's another way you could do it (requires GNU awk):

```
dir="SomeString"
new_dir=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{$1=tolower($1)}1' <<<"$dir")
```

This sets the input and output field separators to an empty string, so each character is a field. The `tolower` function does what you think it does. `1` at the end prints the line. If your shell doesn't support `<<<` you can do `echo "$dir" | awk ...` instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a POSIX compliant solution then have a look at [typeset](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?typeset%201).

```
var='SomeString'
typeset -lL1 b="$var"
echo "${b}${var#?}"
```

#### Output:

```
someString
```

The `typeset` command creates a special variable that is lowercase, left aligned and one char long. `${var#?}` trims the first occurrence of pattern from the start of `$var` and `?` matches a single
character.