# How switch a specific expression to lower case in a file (linux command)

Tags: c++, linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to find a command or to create a script on linux allowing to switch a specific expression to lower-case in many files in subdirectories.

I need this to change the case in all the includes statements in a C++ project (Porting Visual studio project to linux)

So in many files I have

```
#include <Path1/pAth2/naMeofTheHeader.h>
```

and i would like to change it to

```
#include <Path1/pAth2/nameoftheheader.h>
```

(Of course I don't want the path to be moved in lower case)

Does anyone have an idea to perform this? I tried somme sed command (with \L) but anything have worked.

Thanks

Comment: Refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting

Comment: You should always show what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
sed 's~\(#include .*\/\)\([^\/.]*\)~\1\L\2~g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo '#include <Path1/pAth2/naMeofTheHeader.h>' | sed 's~\(#include .*\/\)\([^\/.]*\)~\1\L\2~g'
#include <Path1/pAth2/nameoftheheader.h>
```

Comment: This is a little less leaning-toothpick-y: `sed '/^#include <.*>/ s#[^/]\+$#\L&#'`