# Format output in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, formatting

I have output in bash that I would like to format.  Right now my output looks like this:

```
1scom.net 1
1stservicemortgage.com 1
263.net 1
263.sina.com 1
2sahm.org 1
abac.com 1
abbotsleigh.nsw.edu.au 1
abc.mre.gov.br 1
ableland.freeserve.co.uk 1
academicplanet.com 1
access-k12.org 1
acconnect.com 1
acconnect.com 1
accountingbureau.co.uk 1
acm.org 1
acsalaska.net 1
adam.com.au 1
ada.state.oh.us 1
adelphia.net 1
adelphia.net 1
adelphia.net 1
adelphia.net 1
adelphia.net 1
adelphia.net 1
adelphia.net 1
adelphia.net 1
adelphia.net 1
adelphia.net 1
adelphia.net 1
adelphia.net 1
aecom.yu.edu 1
aecon.com 1
aetna.com 1
agedwards.com 1
ahml.info 1
```

The problem with this is none of the numbers on the right line up.  I would like them to look like this:

```
1scom.net                 1
1stservicemortgage.com    1
263.net                   1
263.sina.com              1
2sahm.org                 1
```

Would there be anyway to make them look like this without knowing exactly how long the longest domain is? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The code that outputted this is:

```
grep -E -o -r "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" $ARCHIVE | sed 's/.*@//' | uniq -ci | sort | sed 's/^ *//g' | awk ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } ' > temp2
```

Comment: Pipe to `column -t`.

Comment: Yup. Also there's no reason for the `sed` in there to remove leading spaces. The `awk` command does that for you by default (when you play with fields).

Comment: You can also reduce the noise in the awk component.  `... | uniq -ci | awk '{print $2,$1}' | column -t`  In fact, if you want to provide an example of your source data, I'm sure we can improve the whole command line.  What's inside `$ARCHIVE`? Oh and also, there are [many TLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) which will not fit inside `\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}`.

Comment: There are many email text files inside of ARCHIVE.  How would I capture all domains in a regex @ghoti?

Comment: Waitasec.  Is this the same question as [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29762023/1072112), and [this other one as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29762398)?  Please don't abandon your old questions.  Either clarify them to improve them so they can be answered, or delete them.  If you have better ways of expressing your question, put them IN YOUR QUESTION, don't just ask a new one.

Comment: No, this is not. I fixed that issue but am trying to solve a formatting issue so I thought it would be best fit under a new question.

Comment: Alternately, you can also use `printf`: `printf "%-30s %d\n" $(< test.list)` or `your_command | xargs printf "%-30s %d\n"`. However, `column -t` is better approach.

Answer (score 1):

**ALIGNMENT:**

Just use **cat** with **column** command and thats it:

`cat /path/to/your/file | column -t`

For more details on `column` command refer http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/column.1.html

**EDITED:**

**View file in terminal:**

`column -t < /path/to/your/file`

(as noted by **anishsane**)

**Export to a file:**

`column -t < /path/to/your/file > /output/file`

Comment: This is [UUOC](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html). `column -t < /path/to/your/file` works too.