# Get lowercase subtring in bash

Tags: string, bash

I have discovered how to get my string in bash as lower case:

```
> multi_case='MULTIcaseSTRING'
> echo ${multi_case,,}
multicasestring
```

...and how to get the last two letters of the string:

```
> echo ${multi_case:(-2)}
NG
```

... but I don't know how to combine them.

How do I get the **last two letters** in **lowercase**? If it helps, I know that the string will always be two to five chars long.

Ideally, I'm looking for a fairly short one-liner.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can nest these expansions, so you might be better off defining a function if you find yourself doing these two things together often.

Comment: I have bash 3.2.25 and `echo ${multi_case,,}` throws "Bad Substitution"

Comment: This question has already an answer [here][1]
and you may find other info [here][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting
  [2]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/383352/command-to-convert-an-upper-case-string-to-lower-case

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo The `,,` and `^^` (uppercase) operators were added in `bash` 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "abuse" a for loop for it (in case you are sure that the variable does not contain any wildcards or whitespace):

```
for i in ${multi_case,,}; do echo ${i:(-2)}; done
```

But in practice, I'd go for a temporary variable:

```
TMP=${multi_case,,}; echo ${TMP:(-2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not pure bash but you can use `tr` to get this done in single line:

```
multi_case='MULTIcaseSTRING'
tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]' <<< "${multi_case:(-2)}"
ng
```