# shell scripting parameter ${1, ,}_name

Tags: shell, scripting

I came across shell scripting already present.Trying to undertand what ${1,,} means here :

```
if [[ ${2} -eq 0 ]]; then
delNam${1,,}_delete_$date
```

new to shell scripting.

Comment: it is


down vote

favorite


 


I came across shell scripting already present.Trying to undertand what ${1,,} means here : 

if [[ ${2} -eq 0 ]]; then delNam=${1,,}delete$date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${1,,}` will [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2264537/96588) the first [positional parameter](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters) to lowercase. In other words, if the script was run like `./script.sh FooBar 0` and `$date` is `2016`, the second line will expand to `delNamfoobar_delete_2016`, which will then be run as a command.

Answer (score 0):

${2} is for input for second parameter & delNam${1,,}*delete*$date for input of 1st parameter with current date.