# How lower case the following bash variables assignments in a single line of code?

Tags: bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readonly FQHN=${1:-`hostname -f`}
readonly HOSTNAME=${FQHN%%.*}
```

I am struggling with the syntax to assign `FQHN` to the lower case of either the first command line argument or the output of `hostname -f` in a single assignment.

I have tried to use the various ways to lower case a variable reference contents as given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2264537/177800) but have not been able to integrate them into my code without having to use something like `"${HOSTNAME,,}"` or `"${FQHN,,}"` for every reference since you can not nest string substitutions.

*I am really looking or a solution that does not rely on mutability.*

Comment: `declare -rl HOSTNAME="$FQHN"`. See: `help declare`

Comment: @Cyrus - I like this as well, can you add it as an answer so it can get upvoted? All the years I have used `bash` and I have never come across a mention of the `declare` builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without having to use something like "${HOSTNAME,,}" or "${FQHN,,}" for every reference

Just do it once and assign the result back to the variable:

```
FQHN=${1:-`hostname -f`}
readonly FQHN=${FQHN,,}
HOSTNAME=${FQHN%%.*}
```

I don't know why you want to do it in a single line, but you can join them with `;` or `&&`:

```
FQHN=${1:-`hostname -f`}; readonly FQHN=${FQHN,,}
HOSTNAME=${FQHN%%.*}
```

Or if you want to do it in a single assignment, you can do it the slow and verbose way:

```
readonly FQHN=$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< "${1:-`hostname -f`}")
HOSTNAME=${FQHN%%.*}
```

Comment: If you want the end result to be `readonly`, simply do that when you have the final value. Use a temporary variable (you can make that `readonly`, too!) if you want to be strict about only assigning a value once; but there really is no way to make it more compact than this.

Comment: *slow and verbose* is not a problem if it is also *clear and obvious*, not that anything in `bash` is *clear or obvious* unless you already know what you are doing ...