# How to convert upper case weekday timestamp from upper case to lower case?

Tags: shell, awk, printing, echo

I want to write the script to read the file name in below format.

```
filename.wednesday filename.thursday filename.friday
```

I am using below command but still print the weekday in an Uppercase letter.

```
Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
```

May I know how can convert it to lowercase so that able to read the file?

Comment: filename.wednesday
filename.thursday
filename.friday

Comment: enter code here
     dd="$(date +'%A')"
        DD=$(echo "$dd" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')

         echo "$DD" >>$outputlog 
        echo "tail filename.$DD">>$outputlog

Comment: Use : typeset -l dd . Anything put in that variable will be converted to lowercase.

Comment: tried . But it print null output. Because my variable in weekday format as below. dd="$(date +'%A')" . Want make it into lower case

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. We do not know how you generate those filenames. You talk about a below command, but where is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a string to lower case in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash)

Comment: @snowman0805 Which version of bash are you using ?, both your code and my suggestion works on my linux, using Bash 4.1.2

Comment: @snowman0805, I think you were missing quotes.  Try this:  dd="$(date +'%A')"; DD="$(echo "$dd" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')"; echo "$DD"

Comment: wrt `below command` - you don't have a command in your question. If you have code then add it to your question. See [ask].