# Is there a way to find middle of a pattern and lowercase it in bash

Tags: bash

I am working on decreasing the size of text data.

Example input:

```
example@EXAMPLE.com;example
example@EXAMPLE.com:exmaple
```

Example output:

```
example@example.com;example
example@example.com:exmaple
```

Pseudo code:

```
if line has "@" and ":" or ";"
replace the text between @ and : or ; with lowercase
```

But I have no idea even what tools to use. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Any of these helpful?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't lowercasing all of it? Email addresses are not case sensitive, so why not standardize the whole thing?

Comment: Unfortunately the documents contains passwords after the : or ;

Answer (score 0):

Use the **sed** tool for resolve this problem,

```
cat input_file.txt | sed -e 's/\(.*@\)\([A-Za-z.]\+\)\([;:].*\)/\1\L\2\3/'
```

Regex Explanation:

> \(.*@\) - This pattern matching "example@"
>
> \([A-Za-z.]\+\) - This pattern matching "EXAMPLE.com"
>
> \([;:].*\) - This pattern matching ":exmaple" or ";exmaple"
>
> The **\L** is changed to lowercase of the text

If you want to update the content use **-i** flag in sed command.

***Ex:***

```
sed -i -e 's/\(.*@\)\([A-Za-z.]\+\)\([;:].*\)/\1\L\2\3/' input_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *lot* of data, `awk` will be faster than a shell. The `sed` solutions are fine, but this works too:

```
$: awk '-F[;:]' '{ printf "%s;%s\n", tolower($1), $2 }' x
example@example.com;exaMple
example@example.com;eXmaple
example@example.com;exAmple
example@example.com;exmaplE
example_example.com;Example
example_example.com;eXmaple
example@example.com,example;
```

That defines the `-F`ield separators as a list of `;:` and lowercases the first field. I arbitrarily replaced the delimiter with a standardized `;` - if that doesn't work, this might not be the best solution for you. Stick with the `sed`.

> sprabhakaran beat me to it with a practically identical `sed` solution while I was initially typing, lol. :)

`sed` can.

```
$: cat x
Example@EXAMPLE.cOm;exaMple
exampLe@EXAMPLE.coM:eXmaple
example@EXAMPLE.com;example
example@EXAMPLE.com:exmaple
example_EXAMPLE.com;example
example_EXAMPLE.com:exmaple
example@EXAMPLE.com,example

$: sed -E '/@.+[;:]/s/^(.*)@(.*)([;:])(.*)/\1@\L\2\E\3\4/' x
Example@example.com;exaMple
exampLe@example.com:eXmaple
example@example.com;exAmple
example@example.com:exmaplE
example_EXAMPLE.com;Example
example_EXAMPLE.com:eXmaple
example@EXAMPLE.com,examPle
```

`\L` says to begin lowercasing until `\E` (end) or `\U` (begin uppercasing).

This skips lines that don't have both `@` and `[;:]` (either of `;` or `:`.)

> for small datasets native `bash` might be easier.

It might be a lot simpler however to just downcase the whole thing.

```
$: declare -l line
$: while read line
> do echo "$line"
> done < x
example@example.com;example
example@example.com:exmaple
example@example.com;example
example@example.com:exmaple
example_example.com;example
example_example.com:exmaple
example@example.com,example
```

`declare -l` make a variable always lowercase anything put in it.

---

#### Since case-sensitive passwords prevent that, parse the parts separately.

```
$: while IFS="$IFS:;" read email pass
> do echo "$email [$pass]"
> done < x
example@example.com [exaMple]
example@example.com [eXmaple]
example@example.com [exAmple]
example@example.com [exmaplE]
example_example.com [Example]
example_example.com [eXmaple]
example@example.com,example []
```

As long as the record is properly formatted it works great.
I assume you can check for errors or trust your data.