# How do I lowercase all MD5 hashes inside of a file?

Tags: regex, sed, gnu

I'm reposting this question with more context and examples because admittedly my last post was rushed. I'm trying to find ALL MD5 hashes (based off the regex) and simply lowercase them (regardless of format, and regardless of what else is on the line).

I previously posted a similar question related to lowercasing emails and this was the solved answer (maybe this can assist in finding the answer).

```
sed -e 's/^\([^@]*\)@/\L\1@/' file
```

The MD5 Regex I use is: `[a-f0-9]{32}`

I'll provide some examples now (each line is unique - there's **NOT** a set pattern)

Input data:

```
fwefwe:few32rfwe:3r2frewg:-::d3ewStack:D077F244DEF8A70E5EA758BD8352FCD8
fwefwe:few33rfwe:3r2frewg:-::dsasaewStack:06D80EB0C50B49A509B49F2424E8C805
fwefwe:few34rfwe:3r2f3213ef::2d3ewStack:F1BDF5ED1D7AD7EDE4E3809BD35644B0
fwefwe:few35rf32re4frewgre3frewg:-::d3ewStack:DDE2C7AD63AD86D6A18DE781205D194F
```

Output data:

```
fwefwe:few32rfwe:3r2frewg:-::d3ewStack:d077f244def8a70e5ea758bd8352fcd8
fwefwe:few33rfwe:3r2frewg:-::dsasaewStack:06d80eb0c50b49a509b49f2424e8c805
fwefwe:few34rfwe:3r2f3213ef::2d3ewStack:f1bdf5ed1d7ad7ede4e3809bd35644b0
fwefwe:few35rf32re4frewgre3frewg:-::d3ewStack:dde2c7ad63ad86d6a18de781205d194f
```

Comment: I don't think this is easy to do in `sed`. Do you have to use that?

Comment: `sed` has the `y` command for doing translations, but I don't think you can restrict it to just the part of the line that matches the regexp.

Comment: No not necessarily, I just thought it'd be easiest

Comment: Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817589/lowercase-md5-hash) was closed as duplicate to [this one about lowercasing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash) - why does that one not help?

Comment: Because I'm not lowercasing a singular string. It's a regex, which that question doesn't provide an answer too.

Comment: @StackStackAndStack Your example above about lowercasing an email uses a regexp. Why can't you use the same method?

Comment: @StackStackAndStack the accepted answer has a `sed` snippet that searches and replaces by regex.

Comment: I'm not trying to lowercase all of the data. Only the MD5 hashes. And I don't know how to incorporate the Regex into a command

Comment: Do you want to match `[A-F0-9]{32}` at the end of a string? Or at the end of the string after `:`?

Comment: @StackStackAndStack It seems like you don't really understand how the email replacement is working, or it would be obvious how to do the same thing here. You need to learn how things work, not just copy them without understanding.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [A-F0-9]{32} can appear anywhere on each line, there isnt a strict format. I'm just looking to lowercase it

Comment: Then you already have an answer, you just need to use `-E`, not `-e`. `sed -E 's/[A-F0-9]{32}/\L&/g'`

Comment: Correct solution, thankyou!
Maybe add it as an official comment, and I can Mark as Solved

Comment: But do not edit the question for solution announcement please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -E 's/[A-F0-9]{32}/\L&/g' file
```

If you also want to modify the existing file add `-i` option:

```
sed -i -E 's/[A-F0-9]{32}/\L&/g' file
```

The point is that you need to use an `-E` option to enable POSIX ERE regex syntax and write `{...}` quantifier without escaping. POSIX BRE equivalent will look like `sed -i 's/[A-F0-9]\{32\}/\L&/g' file`.

Also, I added `g` flag to modify *all* match occurrences on a line.

Answer (score 1):

You do it the same way as you did when lowercasing the email. Use the regexp to match part of the line, then use a back-reference in the replacement to pick that up.

```
sed -e 's/[a-fA-F0-9]\{32\}/\L&/' file
```

In the replacement, `&` is replaced with whatever matched the regexp, and `\L` lowercases it.

Comment: Psst, you were missing the escaping of `{` and `}`. `sed` is weird that way `sed -e 's/[a-fA-F0-9]\{32\}/\L&/g'`