# unable to checkout working tree warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I am trying to clone a private repository facing this error

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4oCc.png)

> > Cloning into 'C:\Users\username\folder\word-add-in'...
> > remote: Enumerating objects: 6786, done.
> > remote: Counting objects: 100% (1672/1672), done.
> > remote: Compressing objects: 100% (462/462), done.
> > remote: Total 6786 (delta 1342), reused 1467 (delta 1205), pack-reused 5114
> > Receiving objects: 100% (6786/6786), 4.75 MiB | 614.00 KiB/s, done.
> > Resolving deltas: 100% (5038/5038), done.
> > error: invalid path 'assets/icon-128.png:Zone.Identifier'
> > fatal: unable to checkout working tree
> > warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
> > You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
> > and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

this is git status `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

After this I used `git init` then again clone but still same error.

After `git init` and cloning again now git status is this

> > On branch master
> > No commits yet
> > Untracked files:
> > (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
> > word-add-in/
> > nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

I have some files with name like `icon-128.png_Zone.Identifier` [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrQJY.png)

Comment: did you try 'git status' as the error suggests ? what was the output ?

Comment: @Hujaakbar this is git status `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: I have multiple branches in this repository

Comment: Rename your local repo, try a new clone

Comment: Also check if there is some file path, or file name, you OS not supported.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. `error: invalid path 'assets/icon-128.png:Zone.Identifier`. It seems that you are on Windows. Then you cannot check out a path that has a colon `:` in the name.

Comment: When you issued `git status`, was you current directory the one mentioned in the posted text, `C:\Users\username\folder\word-add-in`, or was it `'C:\Users\username\folder`? If the latter, then that would explain why no Git repository was found.

Comment: Was about to say exactly same thing than @j6t : 1. you **must never** use `git init` **in this `clone` case** and had to `cd` (enter) in the folder repo automatically created by the `clone` (so now you have to clean the repo created one folder above ☹️) 2. your real clone problem is that you have this icon file named strangely and that can't be created on windows file system. It needs to be fixed from a non-windows computer so that you could checkout. But you will always have this wrong the behavior any time you will try to check out commit in the history if you need to do it...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61616948/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Clone+succeeded%2C+but+checkout+failed+invalid+path The list of forbidden characters and filenames: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#naming-conventions

Comment: @j6t @Philippe I have some files with name like `icon-128.png_Zone.Identifier`

Comment: `_` is an allowed character whereas `:` no. Look at "The following reserved characters" in the link provided by @phd

Comment: Character problem appart, it's a very strange practice to happen something after the file extension. Do you have a bug somewhere in a process that generates these file names? For me it needs to be fixed to no more generate files named like that. More like `icon-128_Zone.Identifier.png`

Comment: If your project is public, and you feel comfortable sharing it with us, please do. That way we can try to reproduce the error and help you.

Comment: @AndréLehto thank you but my project is not public I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have files with names containing underscores instead of colons, the issue may not be directly related to those files. However, Git might be interpreting them as having colons due to some underlying issue.

To work around this problem, you can try to clone the repository with the `core.protectNTFS` setting set to false, which should allow Git to handle the file names more gracefully on Windows:

`git config --global core.protectNTFS false`

Then, try cloning the repository again:

```
git clone https://github.com/name/name.git
```

this will skip files with name like `icon-16.png_Zone.Identifier`