# bash script to convert values before an equal sign to lowercase?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to achieve the following results:

I have a command that spits out some env vars to the terminal:

`./script` will output the following:

```
AWS_OKTA_PROFILE=xxx
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xx
AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN=xx
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=xx
```

I want to write this to an output file in another location to be almost the same except like this (but only before the equal sign)

```
[default]
aws_okta_profile=xxx
aws_access_key_id=xxx
aws_secret_access_key=xx
aws_security_token=xx
aws_session_token=xx
```

Notice, I'm also prepending `[default]` to the file.

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash for a starting point.

Comment: `sed 's/\(.*\)=\(.*\)/\L\1=\E\2/g'`

Comment: Thanks @LéaGris but I just see a L prepended and still uppercase here

Comment: ```echo 'AWS_OKTA_PROFILE=xxx' | awk -F= 'FNR==1{print "[default]"}{print tolower($1),$2}' OFS==```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `sed`, `awk` also provides a simple solution. You can use the `'='` as the field-separator and simply convert the first field to lowercase with `tolower()` if the record contains an `'='` sign. (or you can check `NF>1` to check you have more than one field) The `1` at the end of the rule is simply short-hand for `print`. Putting it altogether, you can use

```
awk -F= -v OFS='=' '/=/{$1=tolower($1)}1' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in the file `file`, you would get:

```
$ awk -F= -v OFS='=' '/=/{$1=tolower($1)}1' file
[default]
aws_okta_profile=xxx
aws_access_key_id=xxx
aws_secret_access_key=xx
aws_security_token=xx
aws_session_token=xx
```

`awk` does not have an edit in-place mechanism (except by non-standard extension), so simply redirect the output to a new file, e.g.

```
$ awk -F= -v OFS='=' '/=/{$1=tolower($1)}1' file > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

The search and replace with lowercase can be done with sed like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S sed -f
s/\([^=]\+\)=\([^=]\+\)/\L\1=\E\2/
```

- `s/\([^=]\+\)=\([^=]\+\)/`: search regex pattern:

  - `\([^=]\+\)`: capture group of 1 or more characters not an `=` sign,
  - `=`: followed by an `=` sign,
  - `\([^=]\+\)`: followed by another captured group of 1 or more characters not an `=` sign.
- `/\L\1=\E\2/`: Replace matches with this:

  - `\L\1`: Lowercase the captured group 1,
  - `=`: followed by an `=` sign,
  - `\E\2`: followed by captured group 2 with case unchanged.

Comment: The `\L` escape is not very portable, though I guess this will work with GNU `sed`.

Comment: Im getting: 

env | grep -i aws | s/\([^=]\+\)=\([^=]\+\)/\L\1=\E\2/
zsh: no matches found: s/([^=]+)=([^=]+)/L1=E2/
[1]    24128 done         env |
       24129 broken pipe  grep --color=auto --exclude-dir={.bzr,CVS,.git,.hg,.svn,.idea,.tox} -i aws

Comment: `grep -i aws | sed 's/([^=]\+)=([^=]\+)/\L\1=\E\2/' > newfile`

Comment: This solution supposes that you save this in a file and make it executable. On the command line, you'd prepend `sed` and put single quotes around the script. (You could easily factor out the `grep` too; `sed '/[Aa][Ww][Ss]/s/\([^=]...'` (there is no simple flag to make `sed` match case-insensitively, though maybe GNU has that too).

Comment: @Ryan this is the issue with asking for code without having done some research. You end-up copy-pasting code you don't understand, and it cannot work, as you cannot ride a horse's tail if it is not attached to the horse.

Comment: Also, one of the perils of attempting to answer questions which don't demonstrate any effort; you can't gauge the level of the OP.

Comment: @tripleee I made the solution unusable as a copy-paste deliberately as a bottle at the sea to invite Ryan to do some research and understand the code before using it.