# Using sed to uppercase all characters before "="

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following string: `abcd=efgh` and I would like to uppercase all characters before the `=` to get `ABCD=efgh`.

After reading a bunch of posts, I tried the following:

`echo "abcd=efgh" | sed -r 's/^(.*)=/\U\1\E=/'`

But this returns:
`UabcdE=efgh`

So with the command, I can capture the right group but the `\U` doesn't uppercase the capture group.
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't have to be `sed` necessarily, it's just what I found when I was searching for an answer

Comment: This can be easily adapted to your question: [bash script to convert values before an equal sign to lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63197734/3776858)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you discovvered, you're running into the difference between GNU sed and BSD sed; the latter is what ships on macOS. If you install GNU sed (e.g. the Homebrew `gnu-sed` package) and use that (probably installed as `gsed`), then your original attempt will work.

A more portable solution would be to use perl. Your original `sed` expression works unchanged:

```
$ echo "abcd=efgh"  |  perl -pe 's/^(.*)=/\U\1\E=/'       
ABCD=efgh
```

Although I would simplify the expression a bit and replace the `echo |` with a here-string:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^[^=]*/\U$&/' <<<'abcd=efgh'
ABCD=efgh
```

There are other tools you could use, but they don't drop right in with the same syntax as sed like perl does. For example, you could use shell builtins to split the string and then run `tr` on the half you want to capitalize:

```
IFS== read left right <<<abcd=efgh
printf '%s=%s\n' "$(tr a-z A-Z <<<"$left")" "$right"
```

If you're using zsh, you can use its built-in uppercase expansion instead of `tr`:

```
IFS== read left right <<<abcd=efgh
printf '%s=%s\n' "${(U)left}" "$right"
```

Newer bash versions can do it, too, but not the one that ships in /bin/ on macOS. You have to install a newer one (for example with Homebrew again), and then this works:

```
IFS== read left right <<<abcd=efgh
printf '%s=%s\n' "${left^^}" "$right"
```

Comment: I wonder if `declare -u left` would work on the ancient bash version that comes on macs.

Comment: Answering my own question, no. It was added at the same time as the `^^` and `,,` expansions.

Comment: `declare -u` does have the advantage of working in both (a new-enough) bash and zsh.  Add ksh to the mix if you use `typeset` instead of `declare`, which works in all three.

Answer (score 4):

Plenty of solutions. Here one using `awk`:

```
awk -F= '{print toupper($1) "=" $2}' <<< 'abcd=efgh'
ABCD=efgh
```

Comment: If you're using = as the input field separator, you might as well use it as the output one, too. I'd write it like this: `awk -v{,O}FS== '{$1 = toupper($1)}1'`

Comment: @MarkReed nice brevity with `-v{,O}FS=` - I haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/;G;s/=.*=/=/' file
```

Make a copy of the current line.

Translate all lowercase alpha to uppercase alpha.

Append the copy of the original line.

Remove the portion of the two lines from `=` to `=` and replace it by `=`.

Alternative:

```
sed 's/.*=/\U&/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`, the alternative `\u` option should work.

```
$ sed ':a;s/[a-z]\+=/\u&/;ta;' input_file
ABCD=efgh
```