# How to convert a string to lower case in Bash, when the string is potentially -e, -E or -n?

Tags: string, bash, shell, lowercase

In this question:  [How to convert a string to lower case in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash)

The accepted answer is:

tr:

```
echo "$a" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

awk:

```
echo "$a" | awk '{print tolower($0)}'
```

Neither of these solutions work if $a is -e or -E or -n

Would this be a more appropriate solution:

```
echo "@$a" | sed 's/^@//' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Comment: this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash#comment80656323_2264537 Would be nice to fix the answer. Generally: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: Also relevant: [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) (oh -- now I see that's one of KamilCuk's links above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
printf '%s\n' "$a" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Comment: But note: `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< "Å"` #=> 
Å

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with `tr`.  Since you're using bash, just use the `,` operator in parameter expansion:

```
$ a='-e BAR'
$ printf "%s\n" "${a,,?}"
-e bar
```

Comment: Alas this won't work with a='Å', at least not with bash up to and including 5.1.16

Answer (score 0):

Using `typeset` (or `declare`) you can define a variable to automatically convert data to lower case when assigning to the variable, eg:

```
$ a='-E'
$ printf "%s\n" "${a}"
-E

$ typeset -l a                 # change attribute of variable 'a' to automatically convert assigned data to lowercase
$ printf "%s\n" "${a}"         # lowercase doesn't apply to already assigned data
-E

$ a='-E'                       # but for new assignments to variable 'a'
$ printf "%s\n" "${a}"         # we can see that the data is 
-e                             # converted to lowercase
```

If you need to maintain case sensitivity of the current variable you can always defined a new variable to hold the lowercase value, eg:

```
$ typeset -l lower_a
$ lower_a="${a}"               # convert data to lowercase upon assignment to variable 'lower_a'
$ printf "%s\n" "${lower_a}"
-e
```