# Use boolean variable as lowercase string in Azure Devops YML pipeline script

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have the following variable in my pipeline script:

```yml
variables:
  is_main: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')]
```

And I want to use it like this:

```yml
- script: npm run build -- --source-map=$(is_main)
```

Unfortunately that leads to an error because "True" is not allowed:

```
> ng build "--source-map=True"

Cannot parse arguments. See below for the reasons.
    Argument --source-map could not be parsed using value "True".Valid type(s) is: boolean
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Angular build
```

I need to lowercase the boolean, and I want to do so in the `script` step to keep the variable in the pipeline as a true boolean (as opposed to a string) until the last possible moment. I've tried several options. To summarize:

Option 1 `$(is_main)` leads to:

> ```
> Argument --source-map could not be parsed using value "True".Valid type(s) is: boolean
> ```

Option 2 `$[lower($(is_main))]` leads to:

> ```
> lower(True): syntax error in expression (error token is "(True)")
> ```

Option 3 `$[lower(variables('is_main'))]` leads to:

> ```
>  lower(variables('is_main')): syntax error in expression (error token is "(variables('is_main'))")
> ```

Option 4 `$[lower(variables['is_main'])]` leads to:

> ```
>  lower(variables['is_main']): syntax error in expression (error token is "(variables['is_main'])")
> ```

Option 5 `${{ lower(variables.is_main) }}` (which should not work as far as I could tell from documenation, because it is not used for runtime evaluation, but hey....) leads to:

> ```
> eq(variables['build.sourcebranch'], 'refs/heads/main'): syntax error in expression (error token is "(variables['build.sourcebranch'], 'refs/heads/main')")
> ```

I've read through [the "Expressions" documentation on Azure Pipelines MSDN pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) and my above attempts are based on it already.

What is the proper way to convert a boolean variable in an Azure Devops pipeline to a lowercase string to be used inside a script step?

---

Footnote:

For now I use this *workaround*:

```
variables:
  is_main: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')]
  generate_source_maps: $[lower(variables['is_main'])] # script step requires lowercase boolean
```

And use it like this:

```
- script: npm run build -- --source-map=$(generate_source_maps)
```

Quite suboptimal because `generate_source_maps` is a *string* whereas the name suggests it's a boolean, and the conversion to lowercase happens very far from the place in the yml where it is relevant and obvious that this is needed. But it works.

Answer (score 3):

My team and I encountered a similar problem just now [A], and `convertToJson` worked for us as a way to convert a Pipeline `boolean` value to lowercase string literal.

Since your initial value is a non-static variable, I don't think you can inline this expression into your `script` line though [B] - you probably still need an extra variable.

Perhaps this would work for you?

```
variables:
  is_main: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')]
  is_main_str: $[convertToJson(variables['is_main'])]

- script: npm run build -- --source-map=$(is_main_str)
```

[A]: Specifically, we wanted to pass a Pipeline parameter value of type `boolean` to an ARM template parameter via `overrideParameters` on an [`AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/acc64cc7292c98597908325e53af9f898a896189/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3#azure-resource-manager-arm-template-deployment-task).

[B]: According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops), `Compile time expressions can be used anywhere; runtime expressions can be used in variables and conditions.`, and only runtime  expressions can access non-static variables. Looks like the `$()` macro syntax cannot evaluate an expression.

Answer (score 1):

> Use boolean variable as lowercase string in Azure Devops YML pipeline script

You could try to below scripts:

```
variables:
  is_main: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')]

- script: npm run build -- --source-map=$(echo "$(is_main)" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")
```

If above not work for you, please try to use below scripts:

```
variables:
  Branch: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/Dev_Test5')] 
  is_main: $(echo "$(Branch)" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")

- script: npm run build -- --source-map=$(is_main)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Can confirm the first one works.

Comment: Can you explain why/how it works? Possibly tell me where to find the documentation on this? The [expressions documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) doesn't show anything on this, does it perhaps rely on doing the lowercase conversion with some shell magic instead of yml?

Comment: Ah, yeah, I reckon it comes from [this POSIX way of doing things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2264537/419956)?

Comment: @Jeroen, Yes, I also refer from it. Glad to know that help you, you could accept it as answer.

Comment: Cheers. I did upvote your answer and am grateful, but I think I will stick with my initial workaround which I found a tad more maintainable, while I wait/hope for an alternative answer that's YML / DevOps based. (I really hope there's just a syntax I missed allowing me to inline my workaround in a task.)

Comment: @Jeroen, I got you. I tried it, but there seems to be no such method, looking forward to whether other community members will give surprises.

Comment: Agreed! And thx again for your help, much appreciated !