# "Bad substitution" doing case conversion (${var,,}) with MacOS /bin/bash

Tags: bash, macos

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ${1,,} = herbert ]; then
        echo "On you're the boss here. Welcome"
elif [ ${1,,} = help ]; then
        echo "Just enter your username, duh"
else
        echo "I don't know who you are. But you're not the boss of me"
fi
~                                                                               
~
```

it's a simple bash script that check if the user input matches the name output. I checked all resources online and cannot find solution to this

I tried replacing curly brackets with normal parentheses and did not yield any better result.

Comment: MacOS's default bash is too old to support `${var,,}`. If you have a newer one earlier in your PATH, change `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to _use_ that newer release. Otherwise, you'll probably want to do something like `name=$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<"$1")` and then checking the value of the name variable instead of the value of `$1`.

Comment: BTW, you want `"${1,,}"` _with the double quotes_; otherwise, arguments with spaces, globs, etc. will behave in contextually-dependent ways. (For example, `./yourscript '1 = 1 -o foo'` will say you're the boss, even though obviously it isn't being given the name herbert).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to lower case in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash)

Comment: On a Mac I'd just write zsh scripts instead of bash ones. (in zsh it's `${(L)1}` to get the lower cased contents of `$1`)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with the ancient version of bash shipped by Apple, you don't have `${var,,}` or `${var^^}` available. Consider using `shopt -s nocasematch` instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nocasematch

case $1 in
  herbert) echo "You're the boss here. Welcome";;
  help)    echo "Just enter your username, duh";;
  *)       echo "I don't know who you are. But you're not the boss of me.";;
esac
```

---

Alternately, at a performance penalty, you could use `tr`:

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<"$1")

if [ "$name" = herbert ]; then
  echo "You're the boss here. Welcome"
elif [ "$name" = help ]; then
  echo "Just enter your username, duh"
else
  echo "I don't know who you are. But you're not the boss of me."
fi
```

---

Better, if you *have* a newer bash installed in your PATH, change your shebang from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to perform a PATH lookup to find the bash executable, and your original code will work (though you should either add quotes or switch to `case` to avoid bugs when the user enters a name with a space).