# Bash: Rename files using pipe

Tags: linux, bash, file, rename

At the beginning, I have to say I've never used Linux (and bash) before, so please be forgiving :)
(Also: sorry if I duplicate a topic - yes, I searched stack but didn't find a good answer).

The problem is - I have to write a **pipe**, which rename all the files (and only files) in current directory - all uppercase to lower.
For example:

```
   File.txt >>> file.txt
   FiLeEeE2.jpG >>> fileeee2.jpg
   FILE.rtf >>> file.rtf
```

All I know is I (probably) should use `ls -1`, `mv`, `sed` and `|`, but I don't know how to merge it :/

Thanks for your help and time.
J.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152514/how-to-rename-all-folders-and-files-to-lowercase-on-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the below `find` command on the directory where the files you want to rename is located.

```
find . -type f -exec rename 's/(.*)/\L$1/' {} \;
```

Comment: Thank a lot, works perfectly! For others, if you change `\L$1` to `\U$1` it will change all lowercase to upper.