# PHP: rename all files to lower case in a directory recursively

Tags: php, lowercase

I need help. I want to rename all files to lower case within a directory recursively. I have a code to test but it only rename within that folder not recursively. How can I make it to do it recursively.

This is the code I use

```
<?php
 $directory="/data";
 $files = scandir($directory);
 foreach($files as $key=>$name){
    $oldName = $name;
    $newName = strtolower($name);
    rename("$directory/$oldName","$directory/$newName");
  }
?>
```

Comment: *nix or windows? often the os is better for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152514/how-to-rename-all-folders-and-files-to-lowercase-on-linux

Comment: @Dagon a php code, that can be use in windows and ubuntu.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the SPL's [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) for that.

```
<?php
$path = realpath('your/path/here');

$di = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach($di as $name => $fio) {
    $newname = $fio->getPath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . strtolower( $fio->getFilename() );
    echo $newname, "\r\n";
    //rename($name, $newname); - first check the output, then remove the comment...
}
```

Comment: @VolkerK: Will this method also change case of the directory name?

Comment: No, it will not change the name of the directories. Because of `RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY` (and SKIP_DOTS) only files but not directories will be handled. If you want to rename the directories as well  ...I guess `CHILD_FIRST` instead of `LEAVES_ONLY` will do the trick.

Comment: Just to mention, FileSystemIterator requires PHP >= 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly for me.

```
<?php
$dir= "path/";

    if($handle=opendir($dir)) {
        while($fileName=readdir($handle)){
            if(strlen($fileName)<100)  // 
            continue;
            $new_fn=strtolower($fn);
            rename($dir.$fileName,$dir.$new_fn);
        }
    }
?>
```