# Renaming files with its path name to proper case using zmv or rename

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zsh, batch-rename

How can I convert all filenames and leading directories to titlecase (proper case) using zmv command.

One starting example I found to start with at :

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv '(*).(*)' '${(C)1}.$2'
```

The above would not work if files are within subdirectories.

or [here](http://www.unix.com/302137697-post2.html)

```
zmv '(**/)(*)~CVS~**/CVS' '${(C)1}${(L)2}'
```

To recursively lowercase files and directories where the name is not CVS. This one would try to copy lower-case filenames to title-case directories (which does not yet exist and hence would not work either.

The following works well if trying to convert to lowercase (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/152741/631775):

```
find my_root_dir -depth -exec rename 's/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\L$2/' {} \;
```

But I would like to make proper case here.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the Perl-script version of `rename` AKA `prename`.

```
find -depth -execdir rename 's/.*/\L$&/;s/[[:lower:]]+/\u$&/g' {} \;
```

It lowercases the whole name then uppercases the first letter of each word.

Since all characters are already lowercase after the first `s` command, `[[:lower:]]+` could be simplified to `.+`.

Note that "word" is loosely defined, for example, "ABC6DEF7GHI" would become "Abc6Def7Ghi".

Answer (score 0):

The following seemed to work for me :

```
zmv '(**/)(*)(**)' '$1${(C)2}'
```

Is there any issue in using this, some outlier case which is not covered. Also could someone please provide a `rename` version as well if possible.