# how could I use complete penn treebank dataset inside python/nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus, penn-treebank

I'm trying to learn using [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) package in python. In particular, I need to use penn tree bank dataset in NLTK. As far as I know, If I call `nltk.download('treebank')` I can get the 5% of the dataset. However, I have a complete dataset in tar.gz file and I want to use it. In   [here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html#parsed-corpora) it is said that:

> If you have access to a full installation of the Penn Treebank, NLTK
>   can be configured to load it as well. Download the ptb package, and in
>   the directory nltk_data/corpora/ptb place the BROWN and WSJ
>   directories of the Treebank installation (symlinks work as well). Then
>   use the ptb module instead of treebank:

So, I opened the python from terminal, imported nltk and typed `nltk.download('ptb')` . With this command, "ptb" directory has been created under my `~/nltk_data` directory. At the end, now I have `~/nltk_data/ptb` directory. Inside there, as suggested in the link I gave above, I've put my dataset folder. So this is my final directory hierarchy.

```
    $: pwd
    $: ~/nltk_data/corpora/ptb/WSJ
    $: ls
    $:00  02  04  06  08  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24
      01  03  05  07  09  11  13  15  17  19  21  23  merge.log
```

Inside all of the folders from 00 to 24, there are many  `.mrg` files such as `wsj_0001.mrg , wsj_0002.mrg`  and so on.

Now, Lets return my question. Again, according to [here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html#parsed-corpora) :

I should be able to obtain the file ids if I write the followings:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import ptb
>>> print(ptb.fileids()) # doctest: +SKIP
['BROWN/CF/CF01.MRG', 'BROWN/CF/CF02.MRG', 'BROWN/CF/CF03.MRG', 'BROWN/CF/CF04.MRG', ...]
```

Unfortunately, when I type `print(ptb.fileids())` I got empty array.

```
>>> print(ptb.fileids())
[]
```

Is there anyone who could help me ?

**EDIT**
here is the content of my ptb directory and some of allcats.txt file :

```
   $: pwd
    $: ~/nltk_data/corpora/ptb
    $: ls
    $: allcats.txt  WSJ
    $: cat allcats.txt
    $: WSJ/00/WSJ_0001.MRG news
    WSJ/00/WSJ_0002.MRG news
    WSJ/00/WSJ_0003.MRG news
    WSJ/00/WSJ_0004.MRG news
    WSJ/00/WSJ_0005.MRG news

    and so on ..
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PTB corpus reader needs uppercase directory and file names (as hinted by the contents of `allcats.txt` that you included in your question). This clashes with many distributions of Penn Treebank out there, which use lowercase.

A quick fix for this would be renaming the folders `wsj` and `brown` and their contents to uppercase. A UNIX command you can use for this is:

```
find . -depth | \
    while read LONG 
    do 
        SHORT=$( basename "$LONG" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' )
        DIR=$( dirname "$LONG" ) 
        if [ "${LONG}" != "${DIR}/${SHORT}"  ] 
        then 
            mv "${LONG}" "${DIR}/${SHORT}" 
        fi 
    done
```

(Obtained from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152514/how-to-rename-all-folders-and-files-to-lowercase-on-linux)). It will change directory and file names to uppercase recursively.