# How to pass files to a script that processes folders

Tags: bash, file, recursion, directory

So I have this bash script which will rename all the files from the current directory. I need help modifying it so I can instead specify only certain files which will be renamed, but also still have the ability to pass it a directory instead. I'm not super familiar with bash so it's fairly confusing to me.

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# Filename: rename.sh
# Description: Renames files and folders to lowercase recursively
#              from the current directory
# Variables: Source = x
#            Destination = y

#
# Rename all directories. This will need to be done first.
#

# Process each directory’s contents before the directory  itself
for x in `find * -depth -type d`;
do

  # Translate Caps to Small letters
  y=$(echo $x | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]');

  # check if directory exits
  if [ ! -d $y ]; then
    mkdir -p $y;
  fi

  # check if the source and destination is the same
  if [ "$x" != "$y" ]; then

    # check if there are files in the directory
    # before moving it
    if [ $(ls "$x") ]; then
      mv $x/* $y;
    fi
    rmdir $x;

  fi

done

#
# Rename all files
#
for x in `find * -type f`;
do
  # Translate Caps to Small letters
  y=$(echo $x | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]');
  if [ "$x" != "$y" ]; then
    mv $x $y;
  fi
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Check you script with [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename all folders and files to lowercase on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152514/how-to-rename-all-folders-and-files-to-lowercase-on-linux)

Comment: **Short && Fast**: `rename -v -n 'tr/a-z/A-Z/' *` or the opposite:  `rename -v -n 'tr/A-Z/a-z/' * `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has a large number of beginner errors, but the actual question in the title has some merit.

For a task like this, I would go for a recursive solution.

```
tolower () {
    local f g
    for f; do
        # If this is a directory, process its contents first
        if [ -d "$f" ]; then
            # Recurse -- run the same function over directory entries
            tolower "$f"/*
        fi
        # Convert file name to lower case (Bash 4+)
        g=${f,,}
        # If lowercased version differs from original, move it
        if [ "${f##*/}" != "${g##*/}" ]; then
            mv "$f" "$g"
        fi
    done
}
```

Notice how variables which contain file names *always* need to be quoted (otherwise, your script will fail on file names which contain characters which are shell metacharacters) and how Bash has [built-in functionality for lowercasing a variable's value](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#case_modification) (in recent versions).

Also, tangentially, [don't use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human debugging help.