# How to rename only the parent folder to lowercase using command line?

Tags: linux, shell, debian

I have the following structure:

```
/mnt
--/source
----/file_groups
------/fg_1900
--------/A
--------/B
------/FG_1901
```

What I would like to do is rename all directories in the `/file_groups` folder to lowercase. But only the parent directory. So it will not change `/A`, or `/B`. However, it will rename `/FG_1901` to `/fg_1901`.

I see this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152514/how-to-rename-all-folders-and-files-to-lowercase-on-linux), but this will do it for all files/folders. I only want the parent folder, and not subs.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tweak it like this:

```
cd file_groups

find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec rename 's/(.*)/\L$1/' {} \;
```

`-maxdepth 1` will only go one level deep to find directories

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to use the depth, but it was maxdepth I was missing. Appreciate it. Will accept once I can.