# Bash to rename files to append folder name

Tags: bash, macos, rename, finder

In folders and subfolders, I have a bunch of images named by date. I'm trying to come up with a script to look into a folder/subfolders and rename all jpg files to add the folder name.

Example:

/Desktop/Trip 1/200512 1.jpg

/Desktop/Trip 1/200512 2.jpg

would became:

/Desktop/Trip 1/Trip 1 200512 1.jpg

/Desktop/Trip 1/Trip 1 200512 2.jpg

I tried tweaking this script but I can't figure out how to get it to add the new part. I also don't know how to get it to work on subfolders.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ignore case, i.e. process *.JPG and *.jpg
shopt -s nocaseglob
shopt -s nullglob

cd ~/Desktop/t/

# Get last part of directory name
here=$(pwd)
dir=${here/*\//}
i=1
for image in *.JPG 
do
   echo mv "$image" "${dir}${name}.jpg"
   ((i++))
done
```

Comment: Have you checked this one out already ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152514/how-do-i-rename-all-folders-and-files-to-lowercase-on-linux

Comment: @souser I don't understand, I don't wish to rename to lowercase but to add the subfolder name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` with the `-iname` option for a case insensitive match and a small script to loop over the images:

```
find /Desktop -iname '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
  for img; do
    parentdir=${img%/*}      # leave the parent dir (remove the last `/` and filename)
    dirname=${parentdir##*/} # leave the parent directory name (remove all parent paths `*/`)
    echo mv -i "$img" "$parentdir/$dirname ${img##*/}"
  done
' sh {} +
```

This extracts the parent path for each image path (like the `dirname` command) and the directory name (like `basename`) and constructs a new output filename with the parent directory name before the image filename.

Remove the `echo` if the output looks as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your for loop. Note that '' is used to that the script can deal with spaces in the file names.

```
for image in "$search_dir"*.JPG
do
    echo mv "'$image'" "'${dir} ${image}'"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for getting it to rname in the current folder. IS there a way to make it work on subfolders too? I think I would need the -R or -regex flags, right? But where would I place it?